# Efficient Algorithm for Bit Reversal (from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

What is the most efficient algorithm to achieve the following:

`0010 0000 => 0000 0100`

The conversion is from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB.  All bits must be reversed; that is, this is *not* endianness-swapping.

Comment: I think the appropriate name is a bitwise operation.

Comment: I think you meant reversal, not rotation.

Comment: Most ARM processors have a built-in operation for that.  The ARM Cortex-M0 doesn't, and I found using a per-byte table to swap bits is the fastest approach.

Comment: Also see Sean Eron Anderson's [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious).

Comment: Please define "best"

Comment: why is this closed, best should be defined as the fastest way...

Comment: _Best_ requires specific metrics. Is a lookup table with 256 bytes fastest on your processor? Does it fit in L1 cache? Does trashing L1 cache affect the performance of other code? Are you looking for the shortest code for some specific processor? ...

Comment: For ARMv7-a, you have GCC inline assembly: `__asm__ ("rbit %0, %1" : "=r" (value) : "r" (value));`.

Answer (score 523, accepted):

**NOTE**: All algorithms below are in C, but should be portable to your language of choice (just don't look at me when they're not as fast :)

### Options

**Low Memory (32-bit `int`, 32-bit machine)(from [here](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Bit%20Reversal)):**

```
unsigned int
reverse(register unsigned int x)
{
    x = (((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1));
    x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
    x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
    x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
    return((x >> 16) | (x << 16));

}
```

From the famous [Bit Twiddling Hacks page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html):

**Fastest (lookup table)**:

```
static const unsigned char BitReverseTable256[] = 
{
  0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xC0, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x60, 0xE0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xD0, 0x30, 0xB0, 0x70, 0xF0, 
  0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xC8, 0x28, 0xA8, 0x68, 0xE8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xD8, 0x38, 0xB8, 0x78, 0xF8, 
  0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x24, 0xA4, 0x64, 0xE4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xD4, 0x34, 0xB4, 0x74, 0xF4, 
  0x0C, 0x8C, 0x4C, 0xCC, 0x2C, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x9C, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xFC, 
  0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xC2, 0x22, 0xA2, 0x62, 0xE2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xD2, 0x32, 0xB2, 0x72, 0xF2, 
  0x0A, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0xCA, 0x2A, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0x1A, 0x9A, 0x5A, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0xBA, 0x7A, 0xFA,
  0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xC6, 0x26, 0xA6, 0x66, 0xE6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xD6, 0x36, 0xB6, 0x76, 0xF6, 
  0x0E, 0x8E, 0x4E, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0xAE, 0x6E, 0xEE, 0x1E, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0xDE, 0x3E, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0xFE,
  0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xC1, 0x21, 0xA1, 0x61, 0xE1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xD1, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x71, 0xF1,
  0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xC9, 0x29, 0xA9, 0x69, 0xE9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xD9, 0x39, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xF9, 
  0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xC5, 0x25, 0xA5, 0x65, 0xE5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xD5, 0x35, 0xB5, 0x75, 0xF5,
  0x0D, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0xCD, 0x2D, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xED, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x5D, 0xDD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0x7D, 0xFD,
  0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xC3, 0x23, 0xA3, 0x63, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xD3, 0x33, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xF3, 
  0x0B, 0x8B, 0x4B, 0xCB, 0x2B, 0xAB, 0x6B, 0xEB, 0x1B, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0xDB, 0x3B, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0xFB,
  0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xC7, 0x27, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xD7, 0x37, 0xB7, 0x77, 0xF7, 
  0x0F, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0xCF, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x1F, 0x9F, 0x5F, 0xDF, 0x3F, 0xBF, 0x7F, 0xFF
};

unsigned int v; // reverse 32-bit value, 8 bits at time
unsigned int c; // c will get v reversed

// Option 1:
c = (BitReverseTable256[v & 0xff] << 24) | 
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) | 
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) |
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 24) & 0xff]);

// Option 2:
unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *) &v;
unsigned char * q = (unsigned char *) &c;
q[3] = BitReverseTable256[p[0]]; 
q[2] = BitReverseTable256[p[1]]; 
q[1] = BitReverseTable256[p[2]]; 
q[0] = BitReverseTable256[p[3]];
```

You can extend this idea to 64-bit `int`s, or trade off memory for speed (assuming your L1 Data Cache is large enough), and reverse 16 bits at a time with a 64K-entry lookup table.

---

### Others

**Simple**

```
unsigned int v;     // input bits to be reversed
unsigned int r = v & 1; // r will be reversed bits of v; first get LSB of v
int s = sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT - 1; // extra shift needed at end

for (v >>= 1; v; v >>= 1)
{   
  r <<= 1;
  r |= v & 1;
  s--;
}
r <<= s; // shift when v's highest bits are zero
```

**Faster (32-bit processor)**

```
unsigned char b = x;
b = ((b * 0x0802LU & 0x22110LU) | (b * 0x8020LU & 0x88440LU)) * 0x10101LU >> 16;
```

**Faster (64-bit processor)**

```
unsigned char b; // reverse this (8-bit) byte
b = (b * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;
```

If you want to do this on a 32-bit `int`, just reverse the bits in each byte, and reverse the order of the bytes.  That is:

```
unsigned int toReverse;
unsigned int reversed;
unsigned char inByte0 = (toReverse & 0xFF);
unsigned char inByte1 = (toReverse & 0xFF00) >> 8;
unsigned char inByte2 = (toReverse & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
unsigned char inByte3 = (toReverse & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
reversed = (reverseBits(inByte0) << 24) | (reverseBits(inByte1) << 16) | (reverseBits(inByte2) << 8) | (reverseBits(inByte3);
```

---

### Results

I benchmarked the two most promising solutions, the lookup table, and bitwise-AND (the first one).  The test machine is a laptop w/ 4GB of DDR2-800 and a Core 2 Duo T7500 @ 2.4GHz, 4MB L2 Cache; YMMV.  I used *gcc* 4.3.2 on 64-bit Linux.  OpenMP (and the GCC bindings) were used for high-resolution timers.

**reverse.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

unsigned int
reverse(register unsigned int x)
{
    x = (((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1));
    x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
    x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
    x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
    return((x >> 16) | (x << 16));

}

int main()
{
    unsigned int *ints = malloc(100000000*sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int *ints2 = malloc(100000000*sizeof(unsigned int));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
      ints[i] = rand();

    unsigned int *inptr = ints;
    unsigned int *outptr = ints2;
    unsigned int *endptr = ints + 100000000;
    // Starting the time measurement
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    // Computations to be measured
    while(inptr != endptr)
    {
      (*outptr) = reverse(*inptr);
      inptr++;
      outptr++;
    }
    // Measuring the elapsed time
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    // Time calculation (in seconds)
    printf("Time: %f seconds\n", end-start);

    free(ints);
    free(ints2);

    return 0;
}
```

**reverse_lookup.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

static const unsigned char BitReverseTable256[] = 
{
  0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xC0, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x60, 0xE0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xD0, 0x30, 0xB0, 0x70, 0xF0, 
  0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xC8, 0x28, 0xA8, 0x68, 0xE8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xD8, 0x38, 0xB8, 0x78, 0xF8, 
  0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x24, 0xA4, 0x64, 0xE4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xD4, 0x34, 0xB4, 0x74, 0xF4, 
  0x0C, 0x8C, 0x4C, 0xCC, 0x2C, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x9C, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xFC, 
  0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xC2, 0x22, 0xA2, 0x62, 0xE2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xD2, 0x32, 0xB2, 0x72, 0xF2, 
  0x0A, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0xCA, 0x2A, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0x1A, 0x9A, 0x5A, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0xBA, 0x7A, 0xFA,
  0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xC6, 0x26, 0xA6, 0x66, 0xE6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xD6, 0x36, 0xB6, 0x76, 0xF6, 
  0x0E, 0x8E, 0x4E, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0xAE, 0x6E, 0xEE, 0x1E, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0xDE, 0x3E, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0xFE,
  0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xC1, 0x21, 0xA1, 0x61, 0xE1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xD1, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x71, 0xF1,
  0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xC9, 0x29, 0xA9, 0x69, 0xE9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xD9, 0x39, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xF9, 
  0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xC5, 0x25, 0xA5, 0x65, 0xE5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xD5, 0x35, 0xB5, 0x75, 0xF5,
  0x0D, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0xCD, 0x2D, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xED, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x5D, 0xDD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0x7D, 0xFD,
  0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xC3, 0x23, 0xA3, 0x63, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xD3, 0x33, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xF3, 
  0x0B, 0x8B, 0x4B, 0xCB, 0x2B, 0xAB, 0x6B, 0xEB, 0x1B, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0xDB, 0x3B, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0xFB,
  0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xC7, 0x27, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xD7, 0x37, 0xB7, 0x77, 0xF7, 
  0x0F, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0xCF, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x1F, 0x9F, 0x5F, 0xDF, 0x3F, 0xBF, 0x7F, 0xFF
};

int main()
{
    unsigned int *ints = malloc(100000000*sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int *ints2 = malloc(100000000*sizeof(unsigned int));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
      ints[i] = rand();

    unsigned int *inptr = ints;
    unsigned int *outptr = ints2;
    unsigned int *endptr = ints + 100000000;
    // Starting the time measurement
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    // Computations to be measured
    while(inptr != endptr)
    {
    unsigned int in = *inptr;  

    // Option 1:
    //*outptr = (BitReverseTable256[in & 0xff] << 24) | 
    //    (BitReverseTable256[(in >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) | 
    //    (BitReverseTable256[(in >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) |
    //    (BitReverseTable256[(in >> 24) & 0xff]);

    // Option 2:
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *) &(*inptr);
    unsigned char * q = (unsigned char *) &(*outptr);
    q[3] = BitReverseTable256[p[0]]; 
    q[2] = BitReverseTable256[p[1]]; 
    q[1] = BitReverseTable256[p[2]]; 
    q[0] = BitReverseTable256[p[3]];

      inptr++;
      outptr++;
    }
    // Measuring the elapsed time
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    // Time calculation (in seconds)
    printf("Time: %f seconds\n", end-start);

    free(ints);
    free(ints2);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried both approaches at several different optimizations, ran 3 trials at each level, and each trial reversed 100 million random `unsigned ints`.  For the lookup table option, I tried both schemes (options 1 and 2) given on the bitwise hacks page.  Results are shown below.

**Bitwise AND**

```
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -o reverse reverse.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 2.000593 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 1.938893 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 1.936365 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O2 -o reverse reverse.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.942709 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.991104 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.947203 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O3 -o reverse reverse.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.922639 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.892372 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse
Time: 0.891688 seconds
```

**Lookup Table (option 1)**

```
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.201127 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.196129 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.235972 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O2 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.633042 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.655880 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.633390 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O3 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.652322 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.631739 seconds              
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 0.652431 seconds
```

**Lookup Table (option 2)**

```
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.671537 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.688173 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.664662 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O2 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.049851 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.048403 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.085086 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ gcc -fopenmp -std=c99 -O3 -o reverse_lookup reverse_lookup.c
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.082223 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.053431 seconds
mrj10@mjlap:~/code$ ./reverse_lookup
Time: 1.081224 seconds
```

### Conclusion

**Use the lookup table, with option 1** (byte addressing is unsurprisingly slow) if you're concerned about performance.  If you need to squeeze every last byte of memory out of your system (and you might, if you care about the performance of bit reversal), the optimized versions of the bitwise-AND approach aren't too shabby either.

### Caveat

Yes, I know the benchmark code is a complete hack.  Suggestions on how to improve it are more than welcome.  Things I know about:

- I don't have access to ICC.  This may be faster (please respond in a comment if you can test this out).
- A 64K lookup table may do well on some modern microarchitectures with large L1D.
- -mtune=native didn't work for -O2/-O3 (`ld` blew up with some crazy symbol redefinition error), so I don't believe the generated code is tuned for my microarchitecture.
- There may be a way to do this slightly faster with SSE.  I have no idea how, but with fast replication, packed bitwise AND, and swizzling instructions, there's got to be something there.
- I know only enough x86 assembly to be dangerous; here's the code GCC generated on -O3 for option 1, so somebody more knowledgable than myself can check it out:

**32-bit**

```
.L3:
movl    (%r12,%rsi), %ecx
movzbl  %cl, %eax
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %edx
movl    %ecx, %eax
shrl    $24, %eax
mov     %eax, %eax
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
sall    $24, %edx
orl     %eax, %edx
movzbl  %ch, %eax
shrl    $16, %ecx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
movzbl  %cl, %ecx
sall    $16, %eax
orl     %eax, %edx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rcx), %eax
sall    $8, %eax
orl     %eax, %edx
movl    %edx, (%r13,%rsi)
addq    $4, %rsi
cmpq    $400000000, %rsi
jne     .L3
```

EDIT: I also tried using `uint64_t` types on my machine to see if there was any performance boost.  Performance was about 10% faster than 32-bit, and was nearly identical whether you were just using 64-bit types to reverse bits on two 32-bit `int` types at a time, or whether you were actually reversing bits in half as many 64-bit values.  The assembly code is shown below (for the former case, reversing bits for two 32-bit `int` types at a time):

```
.L3:
movq    (%r12,%rsi), %rdx
movq    %rdx, %rax
shrq    $24, %rax
andl    $255, %eax
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %ecx
movzbq  %dl,%rax
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
salq    $24, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movq    %rdx, %rax
shrq    $56, %rax
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
salq    $32, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movzbl  %dh, %eax
shrq    $16, %rdx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
salq    $16, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movzbq  %dl,%rax
shrq    $16, %rdx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
salq    $8, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movzbq  %dl,%rax
shrq    $8, %rdx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
salq    $56, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movzbq  %dl,%rax
shrq    $8, %rdx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rax), %eax
andl    $255, %edx
salq    $48, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movzbl  BitReverseTable256(%rdx), %eax
salq    $40, %rax
orq     %rax, %rcx
movq    %rcx, (%r13,%rsi)
addq    $8, %rsi
cmpq    $400000000, %rsi
jne     .L3
```

Comment: I think the 8-bit table should be fastest on most architectures, but only benchmarks will tell.

Comment: Right you are!  See results above (in a minute) :)

Comment: -1 for excessively detailed and thorough post. j/k. +1.

Comment: It was an interesting exercise, if not all that fulfilling.  If nothing else, I hope seeing the process is constructive to somebody else who may want to benchmark something more meritorious :)

Comment: The Option 2 results are a fantastic illustration of the impact of byte addressing. Its also an example of how a compiler will struggle to optimise when it cannot deduce the programmers intention, whereas human brain mk.1 has no trouble at all.

Comment: Option 2 also suffers from potential aliasing, I don't know if the compiler is able to deduce the fact that p and q are not overlapping, but if not, it essentially needs to read p[1] after writing q[0], instead of prefetching the entire thing resulting in a tremendous slow down..

Comment: Thought I'd give this its 100th +vote since I just spend 45 minutes trying to figure out what a function did in legacy code just to find that it was documented here :)

Comment: My...God!

I think I've found...what may very well be...a TRUE speciman. I shall have to consult my documents, and do further research, but something tells me (God, help me), that this is by far the greatest, most thorough and useful answer Stack Overflow has yet. Even John Skeet would be both appalled and impressed!

Comment: Its not immediately clear what "Option 1" and "Option 2" refer to, as the beginning of the post only has code for one lookup table.

Comment: Keep in mind that one particular flaw of microbenchmarking (among a list of many others) is that it tends to artificially favor lookup table based solutions. Since the benchmark is repeating the one operation in a loop, it will often find that using a lookup table that just fits in L1 is the fastest, because everything will hit in L1 every time since there is no cache pressure at all. In a real use case, the operation will usually be interleaved with other operations that cause some cache pressure. A miss to RAM could take 10 or 100 times longer than usual, but this is ignored in benchmarks.

Comment: The upshot being that if two solutions are close, I often pick the non-LUT solution (or the one with the smaller LUT) because the real world impact of a LUT can be severe. Even better would be to benchmark each solution "in situ" - where it is actually used in the larger application, with realistic input. Of course, we don't always have time for that, and we don't always know what realistic input is.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I just tried a performance comparison between an 8-bit LUT (256 uint8_t entries) and a 16-bit LUT (65535 uint16_t entries).  Reversing a uint32_t value four billion times took 19.755 seconds for the 8-bit LUT and 11.840 seconds for the 16-bit LUT.  So there is a substantial time saving, but at the cost of 128kb of RAM!

Comment: @Wossname You don't need to store the table in the RAM.

Comment: @Mike, true, I tried paper tape but it snapped on day 19. :D

Comment: `BitReverseTable256[v & 0xff] << 24`
Isn't bit shifting of a `char` by 24 UB?

Answer (score 95):

This thread caught my attention since it deals with a simple problem that requires a lot of work (CPU cycles) even for a modern CPU. And one day I also stood there with the same ¤#%"#" problem. I had to flip millions of bytes. However I know all my target systems are modern Intel-based so let's start optimizing to the extreme!!!

So I used Matt J's lookup code as the base. the system I'm benchmarking on is a i7 haswell 4700eq.

Matt J's lookup bitflipping 400 000 000 bytes: Around 0.272 seconds.

I then went ahead and tried to see if Intel's ISPC compiler could vectorise the arithmetics in the reverse.c.

I'm not going to bore you with my findings here since I tried a lot to help the compiler find stuff, anyhow I ended up with performance of around 0.15 seconds to bitflip 400 000 000 bytes. It's a great reduction but for my application that's still way way too slow..

So people let me present the fastest Intel based bitflipper in the world. Clocked at:

Time to bitflip 400000000 bytes: 0.050082 seconds !!!!!

```
// Bitflip using AVX2 - The fastest Intel based bitflip in the world!!
// Made by Anders Cedronius 2014 (anders.cedronius (you know what) gmail.com)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

#define DISPLAY_HEIGHT  4
#define DISPLAY_WIDTH   32
#define NUM_DATA_BYTES  400000000

// Constants (first we got the mask, then the high order nibble look up table and last we got the low order nibble lookup table)
__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) static unsigned char k1[32*3]={
        0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,
        0x00,0x08,0x04,0x0c,0x02,0x0a,0x06,0x0e,0x01,0x09,0x05,0x0d,0x03,0x0b,0x07,0x0f,0x00,0x08,0x04,0x0c,0x02,0x0a,0x06,0x0e,0x01,0x09,0x05,0x0d,0x03,0x0b,0x07,0x0f,
        0x00,0x80,0x40,0xc0,0x20,0xa0,0x60,0xe0,0x10,0x90,0x50,0xd0,0x30,0xb0,0x70,0xf0,0x00,0x80,0x40,0xc0,0x20,0xa0,0x60,0xe0,0x10,0x90,0x50,0xd0,0x30,0xb0,0x70,0xf0
};

// The data to be bitflipped (+32 to avoid the quantization out of memory problem)
__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) static unsigned char data[NUM_DATA_BYTES+32]={};

extern "C" {
void bitflipbyte(unsigned char[],unsigned int,unsigned char[]);
}

int main()
{

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA_BYTES; i++)
    {
        data[i] = rand();
    }

    printf ("\r\nData in(start):\r\n");
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DISPLAY_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            printf ("0x%02x,",data[i+(j*DISPLAY_WIDTH)]);
        }
        printf ("\r\n");
    }

    printf ("\r\nNumber of 32-byte chunks to convert: %d\r\n",(unsigned int)ceil(NUM_DATA_BYTES/32.0));

    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    bitflipbyte(data,(unsigned int)ceil(NUM_DATA_BYTES/32.0),k1);
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();

    printf ("\r\nData out:\r\n");
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DISPLAY_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            printf ("0x%02x,",data[i+(j*DISPLAY_WIDTH)]);
        }
        printf ("\r\n");
    }
    printf("\r\n\r\nTime to bitflip %d bytes: %f seconds\r\n\r\n",NUM_DATA_BYTES, end_time-start_time);

    // return with no errors
    return 0;
}
```

The printf's are for debugging..

Here is the workhorse:

```
bits 64
global bitflipbyte

bitflipbyte:    
        vmovdqa     ymm2, [rdx]
        add         rdx, 20h
        vmovdqa     ymm3, [rdx]
        add         rdx, 20h
        vmovdqa     ymm4, [rdx]
bitflipp_loop:
        vmovdqa     ymm0, [rdi] 
        vpand       ymm1, ymm2, ymm0 
        vpandn      ymm0, ymm2, ymm0 
        vpsrld      ymm0, ymm0, 4h 
        vpshufb     ymm1, ymm4, ymm1 
        vpshufb     ymm0, ymm3, ymm0         
        vpor        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vmovdqa     [rdi], ymm0
        add     rdi, 20h
        dec     rsi
        jnz     bitflipp_loop
        ret
```

The code takes 32 bytes then masks out the nibbles. The high nibble gets shifted right by 4. Then I use vpshufb and ymm4 / ymm3 as lookup tables. I could use a single lookup table but then I would have to shift left before ORing the nibbles together again.

There are even faster ways of flipping the bits. But I'm bound to single thread and CPU so this was the fastest I could achieve. Can you make a faster version?

Please make no comments about using the Intel C/C++ Compiler Intrinsic Equivalent commands...

Comment: You deserve FAR more upvotes than this. I knew that this should be doable with `pshub`, because after all the best popcount is also done with it! I'd have written it here if not for you. Kudos.

Comment: Thanks! 'popcnt' is another favorite subject of mine ;)  Check out my BMI2 version: result=__tzcnt_u64(~_pext_u64(data[i],data[i]));

Comment: Hah! For that one, I independently figured out something similar, because I noticed that `pext(x, x)`  gathers all the (discontiguous) ones consecutively in the bottom few bits, and hence could be done as `return 64-lzcnt(pext(x,x))`. Admittedly `return tzcnt(~pext(x,x))` is neater and shorter.

Comment: It looks like ymm3/ymm4 contain 16-entry lookup tables repeated twice. Are the repeats of the lookup tables just there to fill space? could ymm3/4 just be zeroed out for the upper 16 bytes?

Comment: From what I recall when playing around with 'vpshufb' is that the most significant (or whatever you want to call them) 16 bytes in the ymmx source register are linked with the 16 most significant bytes in the dest register. So are the 16 least significant bytes.. (also mask register).

Comment: I'm not following why you'd use the pext/tzcnt trick when you could just use popcnt instruction directly in that case?

Comment: I had a wild idea of just maxing out popcnts by interleaving popcnt with BMI2 and AVX2 to in theory utilise all the arithmetic units in the CPU in parallel. However memory is too slow and the outcome of the test was just a new way of popcnting :).. so you are right no need to do any fancy tricks when it comes to popcnt.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473882/fastest-64-bit-population-count-hamming-weight

Comment: How do I compile this with `gcc`?

Comment: Name the asm file : bitflip_asm.s
then: yasm -f elf64 bitflip_asm.s 
Name the c file: bitflip.c
then: g++ -fopenmp bitflip.c bitflip_asm.o -o bitflip

Thats it.

Comment: If you want GCC then remove "using namespace std;" and extern "C" + brackets. then: gcc -std=c99 -fopenmp bitflip.c bitflip_asm.o -o bitflip

Comment: Intel CPUs have the execution units for `popcnt`, `tzcnt`, and `pext` all on port 1.  So every `pext` or `tzcnt` costs you a `popcnt` of throughput.  If your data is hot in L1D cache, the fastest way to popcount an array on Intel CPUs is with AVX2 pshufb.  (Ryzen has 4 per clock `popcnt` throughput so that's probably optimal, but Bulldozer-family has one per 4 clocks `popcnt r64,r64` throughput ...  http://agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: Why are you opposed to using intrinsics?  You could easily get a compiler to emit that loop, or unroll it for you.  Or inline it so it's efficient even for small blocks, keeping the constants hoisted.  The main way you could beat the compiler with asm is by packing the constants more efficiently, and you're not doing that.  e.g. `vpbroadcastd ymm2, [const_0x0f]` / `vbroadcasti128 ymm3, [low_lane]` / `vpslld ymm4, ymm3, 4`.  Broadcast-loads don't need an ALU port, the broadcast happens in the load port with no extra cost.  So this is only 20 bytes of table. Which should be `static` **`const`**.

Comment: Also`add rdx, 0x20` is silly.  An addressing mode like `[rdx + 0x20]` would be more efficient (or `+0x10` if you remove redundancy between lanes).  Passing a single pointer to the table data is not a bad idea, but you might as well have put it in `.rodata` in the asm.  Then you could `lea rdx, [rel my_data]` if you want to optimize for code-size instead of using 2 or 3 RIP-relative loads.  Making the caller pass an extra arg is not cheaper overall.  Nice work with the shuffles, but some of the implementation details are a little clunky, IMO.

Comment: I am using a intrinsics version myself. However when I did answer I posted what I had and I knew from previous posts that as soon I write assembler a smart aleck always points out that I should have done it in intrinsics. When I develop I write assembler first then, when I like the result I move to intrinsics.. That's me.. I just happened to post my answer when I only had my 'test' assembler version.

Answer (score 18):

This is another solution for folks who love recursion.

The idea is simple. 
Divide up input by half and swap the two halves, continue until it reaches single bit.

```
Illustrated in the example below.

Ex : If Input is 00101010   ==> Expected output is 01010100

1. Divide the input into 2 halves 
    0010 --- 1010

2. Swap the 2 Halves
    1010     0010

3. Repeat the same for each half.
    10 -- 10 ---  00 -- 10
    10    10      10    00

    1-0 -- 1-0 --- 1-0 -- 0-0
    0 1    0 1     0 1    0 0

Done! Output is 01010100
```

Here is a recursive function to solve it. (Note I have used unsigned ints, so it can work for inputs up to sizeof(unsigned int)*8 bits.

> The recursive function takes 2 parameters - The value whose bits need
>   to be reversed and the number of bits in the value.

```
int reverse_bits_recursive(unsigned int num, unsigned int numBits)
{
    unsigned int reversedNum;;
    unsigned int mask = 0;

    mask = (0x1 << (numBits/2)) - 1;

    if (numBits == 1) return num;
    reversedNum = reverse_bits_recursive(num >> numBits/2, numBits/2) |
                   reverse_bits_recursive((num & mask), numBits/2) << numBits/2;
    return reversedNum;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int reversedNum;
    unsigned int num;

    num = 0x55;
    reversedNum = reverse_bits_recursive(num, 8);
    printf ("Bit Reversal Input = 0x%x Output = 0x%x\n", num, reversedNum);

    num = 0xabcd;
    reversedNum = reverse_bits_recursive(num, 16);
    printf ("Bit Reversal Input = 0x%x Output = 0x%x\n", num, reversedNum);

    num = 0x123456;
    reversedNum = reverse_bits_recursive(num, 24);
    printf ("Bit Reversal Input = 0x%x Output = 0x%x\n", num, reversedNum);

    num = 0x11223344;
    reversedNum = reverse_bits_recursive(num,32);
    printf ("Bit Reversal Input = 0x%x Output = 0x%x\n", num, reversedNum);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Bit Reversal Input = 0x55 Output = 0xaa
Bit Reversal Input = 0xabcd Output = 0xb3d5
Bit Reversal Input = 0x123456 Output = 0x651690
Bit Reversal Input = 0x11223344 Output = 0x22cc4488
```

Comment: Does this approach fail to work on the 24-bit example(3rd)? 

I'm not quite familiar with C and bitwise operators but from your explanation of the approach I'm guessing 24->12->6->3(3 bits uneven to split). As `numBits` is int, when you divide 3 by 2 for the function param it will be rounded down to 1?

Answer (score 18):

Well this certainly won't be an answer like Matt J's but hopefully it will still be useful.

```
size_t reverse(size_t n, unsigned int bytes)
{
    __asm__("BSWAP %0" : "=r"(n) : "0"(n));
    n >>= ((sizeof(size_t) - bytes) * 8);
    n = ((n & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((n & 0x5555555555555555) << 1);
    n = ((n & 0xcccccccccccccccc) >> 2) | ((n & 0x3333333333333333) << 2);
    n = ((n & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((n & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) << 4);
    return n;
}
```

This is exactly the same idea as Matt's best algorithm except that there's this little instruction called BSWAP which swaps the bytes (not the bits) of a 64-bit number.  So b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0 becomes b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7.  Since we are working with a 32-bit number we need to shift our byte-swapped number down 32 bits.  This just leaves us with the task of swapping the 8 bits of each byte which is done and voila! we're done.

Timing: on my machine, Matt's algorithm ran in ~0.52 seconds per trial.  Mine ran in about 0.42 seconds per trial.  20% faster is not bad I think.

If you're worried about the availability of the instruction BSWAP [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings) lists the instruction BSWAP as being added with 80846 which came out in 1989.  It should be noted that Wikipedia also states that this instruction only works on 32 bit registers which is clearly not the case on my machine, it very much works only on 64-bit registers.

This method will work equally well for any integral datatype so the method can be generalized trivially by passing the number of bytes desired:

```
    size_t reverse(size_t n, unsigned int bytes)
    {
        __asm__("BSWAP %0" : "=r"(n) : "0"(n));
        n >>= ((sizeof(size_t) - bytes) * 8);
        n = ((n & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((n & 0x5555555555555555) << 1);
        n = ((n & 0xcccccccccccccccc) >> 2) | ((n & 0x3333333333333333) << 2);
        n = ((n & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((n & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) << 4);
        return n;
    }
```

which can then be called like:

```
    n = reverse(n, sizeof(char));//only reverse 8 bits
    n = reverse(n, sizeof(short));//reverse 16 bits
    n = reverse(n, sizeof(int));//reverse 32 bits
    n = reverse(n, sizeof(size_t));//reverse 64 bits
```

The compiler should be able to optimize the extra parameter away (assuming the compiler inlines the function) and for the `sizeof(size_t)` case the right-shift would be removed completely.  Note that GCC at least is not able to remove the BSWAP and right-shift if passed `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: According to the Intel Instruction Set Reference Volume 2A (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals) there are two BSWAP instructions: BSWAP r32 (working on 32 bit registers), which is encoded as 0F C8+rd and BSWAP r64 (working on 64 bit registers), which is encoded as REX.W + 0F C8+rd.

Comment: You say it can be used like this: "n = reverse(n, sizeof(size_t));//reverse 64 bits" however this will give only 32bits of result unless all the constants are extended to 64bit, then it works.

Comment: @rajkosto as of C++11 the allowed types of integer literals includes `unsigned long long int` which must be at least 64 bits, as per [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: Ok? I'm just saying that if you want this to work on 64bit values, you have to extend your literals (so they are 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0ull , for example), otherwise the high 32bits of the result will be all 0s.

Comment: @rajkosto Ah, I had misunderstood your first comment, I have fixed that now

Answer (score 16):

[Anders Cedronius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24058332/780717) provides a great solution for people that have an x86 CPU with AVX2 support. For x86 platforms without AVX support or non-x86 platforms, either of the following implementations should work well.

The first code is a variant of the classic binary partitioning method, coded to maximize the use of the shift-plus-logic idiom useful on various ARM processors. In addition, it uses on-the-fly mask generation which could be beneficial for RISC processors that otherwise require multiple instructions to load each 32-bit mask value. Compilers for x86 platforms should use constant propagation to compute all masks at compile time rather than run time.

```c
/* Classic binary partitioning algorithm */
inline uint32_t brev_classic (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t m;
    a = (a >> 16) | (a << 16);                            // swap halfwords
    m = 0x00ff00ff; a = ((a >> 8) & m) | ((a << 8) & ~m); // swap bytes
    m = m^(m << 4); a = ((a >> 4) & m) | ((a << 4) & ~m); // swap nibbles
    m = m^(m << 2); a = ((a >> 2) & m) | ((a << 2) & ~m);
    m = m^(m << 1); a = ((a >> 1) & m) | ((a << 1) & ~m);
    return a;
}
```

In volume 4A of "The Art of Computer Programming", D. Knuth shows clever ways of reversing bits that somewhat surprisingly require fewer operations than the classical binary partitioning algorithms. One such algorithm for 32-bit operands, that I cannot find in TAOCP, is shown in [this document](http://www.hackersdelight.org/revisions.pdf) on the Hacker's Delight website.

```c
/* Knuth's algorithm from http://www.hackersdelight.org/revisions.pdf. Retrieved 8/19/2015 */
inline uint32_t brev_knuth (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t t;
    a = (a << 15) | (a >> 17);
    t = (a ^ (a >> 10)) & 0x003f801f; 
    a = (t + (t << 10)) ^ a;
    t = (a ^ (a >>  4)) & 0x0e038421; 
    a = (t + (t <<  4)) ^ a;
    t = (a ^ (a >>  2)) & 0x22488842; 
    a = (t + (t <<  2)) ^ a;
    return a;
}
```

Using the Intel compiler C/C++ compiler 13.1.3.198, both of the above functions auto-vectorize nicely targetting `XMM` registers. They could also be vectorized manually without a lot of effort.

On my IvyBridge Xeon E3 1270v2, using the auto-vectorized code, 100 million `uint32_t` words were bit-reversed in 0.070 seconds using `brev_classic()`, and 0.068 seconds using `brev_knuth()`. I took care to ensure that my benchmark was not limited by system memory bandwidth.

Comment: @JoelSnyder I assume by "lots of magic numbers" you are primarily referring to `brev_knuth()`? The attribution in the PDF from Hacker's Delight seems to indicate that these numbers are directly from Knuth himself. I cannot claim to have understood Knuth's description of the underlying design principles in TAOCP sufficiently to explain how the constants were derived, or how one would go about the deriving constants and shift factors for arbitrary word sizes.

Answer (score 10):

**This ain't no job for a human!** *... but perfect for a machine*

This is 2015, 6 years from when this question was first asked. Compilers have since become our masters, and our job as humans is only to help them. So what's the best way to give our intentions to the machine?

Bit-reversal is so common that you have to wonder why the x86's ever growing ISA doesn't include an instruction to do it one go.

The reason: if you give your true concise intent to the compiler, bit reversal should only take **~20 CPU cycles**. Let me show you how to craft reverse() and use it:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t reverse(const uint64_t n,
                 const uint64_t k)
{
        uint64_t r, i;
        for (r = 0, i = 0; i < k; ++i)
                r |= ((n >> i) & 1) << (k - i - 1);
        return r;
}

int main()
{
        const uint64_t size = 64;
        uint64_t sum = 0;
        uint64_t a;
        for (a = 0; a < (uint64_t)1 << 30; ++a)
                sum += reverse(a, size);
        printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", sum);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling this sample program with Clang version >= 3.6, -O3, -march=native (tested with Haswell), gives artwork-quality code using the new AVX2 instructions, with a runtime of **11 seconds** processing ~1 billion reverse()s. That's ~10 ns per reverse(), with .5 ns CPU cycle assuming 2 GHz puts us at the sweet 20 CPU cycles.

- *You can fit 10 reverse()s in the time it takes to access RAM once for a single large array!*
- *You can fit 1 reverse() in the time it takes to access an L2 cache LUT twice.*

Caveat: this sample code should hold as a decent benchmark for a few years, but it will eventually start to show its age once compilers are smart enough to optimize main() to just printf the final result instead of really computing anything. But for now it works in showcasing reverse().

Comment: `Bit-reversal is so common...` I don't know about that. I work with code that deals with data at the bit level virtually every day, and I can't recall ever having had this specific need. In what scenarios do you need it? - Not that it isn't an interesting problem to solve in its own right.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I end up needing this function many times in grammar inference with fast, succinct data structures. A normal binary tree encoded as a bitarray ends up inferring the grammar in "big endian" order. But for better generalization if you build a tree (bitarray) with nodes swapped around by the bit-reversal permutation, the learned grammar's strings are in "little endian." That switching allows you to infer variable length strings rather than fixed integer sizes. This situation pops up a lot in efficient FFT as well: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation

Comment: Thanks, I somehow managed to intuit that FFT might be involved in your answer :)

Comment: why just 20 cycles? Which architecture? Is this true for all super wide VLIW architectures of the future till humankind and our descents die out? Just questions, no answers... downvote to hell again

Answer (score 10):

Native ARM instruction "rbit" can do it with 1 cpu cycle and 1 extra cpu register, impossible to beat.

Answer (score 8):

Presuming that you have an array of bits, how about this:
 1. Starting from MSB, push bits into a stack one by one.
 2. Pop bits from this stack into another array (or the same array if you want to save space), placing the first popped bit into MSB and going on to less significant bits from there.

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
Bit[] bits = new Bit[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++) 
{
    stack.push(bits[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    bits[i] = stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: This one made me smile :)  I'd love to see a benchmark of this C# solution against one of the ones I outlined above in optimized C.

Comment: LOL... But hey! the adjective 'best' in the 'best algorithm' is a pretty subjective thing :D

Answer (score 5):

Of course the obvious source of bit-twiddling hacks is here:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious

Answer (score 5):

Implementation with low memory and fastest.

```
private Byte  BitReverse(Byte bData)
    {
        Byte[] lookup = { 0, 8,  4, 12, 
                          2, 10, 6, 14 , 
                          1, 9,  5, 13,
                          3, 11, 7, 15 };
        Byte ret_val = (Byte)(((lookup[(bData & 0x0F)]) << 4) + lookup[((bData & 0xF0) >> 4)]);
        return ret_val;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is basically the same as the first "reverse()" but it is 64 bit and only needs one immediate mask to be loaded from the instruction stream. GCC creates code without jumps, so this should be pretty fast.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long long swap64(unsigned long long val)
{
#define ZZZZ(x,s,m) (((x) >>(s)) & (m)) | (((x) & (m))<<(s));
/* val = (((val) >>16) & 0xFFFF0000FFFF) | (((val) & 0xFFFF0000FFFF)<<16); */

val = ZZZZ(val,32,  0x00000000FFFFFFFFull );
val = ZZZZ(val,16,  0x0000FFFF0000FFFFull );
val = ZZZZ(val,8,   0x00FF00FF00FF00FFull );
val = ZZZZ(val,4,   0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0Full );
val = ZZZZ(val,2,   0x3333333333333333ull );
val = ZZZZ(val,1,   0x5555555555555555ull );

return val;
#undef ZZZZ
}

int main(void)
{
unsigned long long val, aaaa[16] =
 { 0xfedcba9876543210,0xedcba9876543210f,0xdcba9876543210fe,0xcba9876543210fed
 , 0xba9876543210fedc,0xa9876543210fedcb,0x9876543210fedcba,0x876543210fedcba9
 , 0x76543210fedcba98,0x6543210fedcba987,0x543210fedcba9876,0x43210fedcba98765
 , 0x3210fedcba987654,0x210fedcba9876543,0x10fedcba98765432,0x0fedcba987654321
 };
unsigned iii;

for (iii=0; iii < 16; iii++) {
    val = swap64 (aaaa[iii]);
    printf("A[]=%016llX Sw=%016llx\n", aaaa[iii], val);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was curious how fast would be the obvious raw rotation.
On my machine (i7@2600), the average for 1,500,150,000 iterations was `27.28 ns` (over a a random set of 131,071 64-bit integers).

Advantages: the amount of memory needed is little and the code is simple. I would say it is not that large, either. The time required is predictable and constant for any input (128 arithmetic SHIFT operations + 64 logical AND operations + 64 logical OR operations).

I compared to the best time obtained by @Matt J - who has the accepted answer. If I read his answer correctly, the best he has got was `0.631739` seconds for `1,000,000` iterations, which leads to an average of `631 ns` per rotation.

The code snippet I used is this one below:

```
unsigned long long reverse_long(unsigned long long x)
{
    return (((x >> 0) & 1) << 63) |
           (((x >> 1) & 1) << 62) |
           (((x >> 2) & 1) << 61) |
           (((x >> 3) & 1) << 60) |
           (((x >> 4) & 1) << 59) |
           (((x >> 5) & 1) << 58) |
           (((x >> 6) & 1) << 57) |
           (((x >> 7) & 1) << 56) |
           (((x >> 8) & 1) << 55) |
           (((x >> 9) & 1) << 54) |
           (((x >> 10) & 1) << 53) |
           (((x >> 11) & 1) << 52) |
           (((x >> 12) & 1) << 51) |
           (((x >> 13) & 1) << 50) |
           (((x >> 14) & 1) << 49) |
           (((x >> 15) & 1) << 48) |
           (((x >> 16) & 1) << 47) |
           (((x >> 17) & 1) << 46) |
           (((x >> 18) & 1) << 45) |
           (((x >> 19) & 1) << 44) |
           (((x >> 20) & 1) << 43) |
           (((x >> 21) & 1) << 42) |
           (((x >> 22) & 1) << 41) |
           (((x >> 23) & 1) << 40) |
           (((x >> 24) & 1) << 39) |
           (((x >> 25) & 1) << 38) |
           (((x >> 26) & 1) << 37) |
           (((x >> 27) & 1) << 36) |
           (((x >> 28) & 1) << 35) |
           (((x >> 29) & 1) << 34) |
           (((x >> 30) & 1) << 33) |
           (((x >> 31) & 1) << 32) |
           (((x >> 32) & 1) << 31) |
           (((x >> 33) & 1) << 30) |
           (((x >> 34) & 1) << 29) |
           (((x >> 35) & 1) << 28) |
           (((x >> 36) & 1) << 27) |
           (((x >> 37) & 1) << 26) |
           (((x >> 38) & 1) << 25) |
           (((x >> 39) & 1) << 24) |
           (((x >> 40) & 1) << 23) |
           (((x >> 41) & 1) << 22) |
           (((x >> 42) & 1) << 21) |
           (((x >> 43) & 1) << 20) |
           (((x >> 44) & 1) << 19) |
           (((x >> 45) & 1) << 18) |
           (((x >> 46) & 1) << 17) |
           (((x >> 47) & 1) << 16) |
           (((x >> 48) & 1) << 15) |
           (((x >> 49) & 1) << 14) |
           (((x >> 50) & 1) << 13) |
           (((x >> 51) & 1) << 12) |
           (((x >> 52) & 1) << 11) |
           (((x >> 53) & 1) << 10) |
           (((x >> 54) & 1) << 9) |
           (((x >> 55) & 1) << 8) |
           (((x >> 56) & 1) << 7) |
           (((x >> 57) & 1) << 6) |
           (((x >> 58) & 1) << 5) |
           (((x >> 59) & 1) << 4) |
           (((x >> 60) & 1) << 3) |
           (((x >> 61) & 1) << 2) |
           (((x >> 62) & 1) << 1) |
           (((x >> 63) & 1) << 0);
}
```

Comment: @greybeard I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: thanks for noticing the bug, I fixed the code sample provided.

Answer (score 4):

Efficient can mean throughput or latency.

For throughout, see the answer by Anders Cedronius, it’s a good one.

For lower latency, I would recommend this code:

```
uint32_t reverseBits( uint32_t x )
{
#if defined(__arm__) || defined(__aarch64__)
    __asm__( "rbit %0, %1" : "=r" ( x ) : "r" ( x ) );
    return x;
#endif
    // Flip pairwise
    x = ( ( x & 0x55555555 ) << 1 ) | ( ( x & 0xAAAAAAAA ) >> 1 );
    // Flip pairs
    x = ( ( x & 0x33333333 ) << 2 ) | ( ( x & 0xCCCCCCCC ) >> 2 );
    // Flip nibbles
    x = ( ( x & 0x0F0F0F0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( x & 0xF0F0F0F0 ) >> 4 );

    // Flip bytes. CPUs have an instruction for that, pretty fast one.
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    return _byteswap_ulong( x );
#elif defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    return (uint32_t)_bswap( (int)x );
#else
    // Assuming gcc or clang
    return __builtin_bswap32( x );
#endif
}
```

Compilers output: https://godbolt.org/z/5ehd89

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the standard template library. It might be slower than the above mentioned code. However, it seems to me clearer and easier to understand.

```
 #include<bitset>
 #include<iostream>


 template<size_t N>
 const std::bitset<N> reverse(const std::bitset<N>& ordered)
 {
      std::bitset<N> reversed;
      for(size_t i = 0, j = N - 1; i < N; ++i, --j)
           reversed[j] = ordered[i];
      return reversed;
 };


 // test the function
 int main()
 {
      unsigned long num; 
      const size_t N = sizeof(num)*8;

      std::cin >> num;
      std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex;
      std::cout << "ordered  = " << num << std::endl;
      std::cout << "reversed = " << reverse<N>(num).to_ulong()  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "double_reversed = " << reverse<N>(reverse<N>(num)).to_ulong() << std::endl;  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Generic**

C code. Using 1 byte input data num as example.

```
    unsigned char num = 0xaa;   // 1010 1010 (aa) -> 0101 0101 (55)
    int s = sizeof(num) * 8;    // get number of bits
    int i, x, y, p;
    int var = 0;                // make var data type to be equal or larger than num

    for (i = 0; i < (s / 2); i++) {
        // extract bit on the left, from MSB
        p = s - i - 1;
        x = num & (1 << p);
        x = x >> p;
        printf("x: %d\n", x);

        // extract bit on the right, from LSB
        y = num & (1 << i);
        y = y >> i;
        printf("y: %d\n", y);

        var = var | (x << i);       // apply x
        var = var | (y << p);       // apply y
    }

    printf("new: 0x%x\n", new);
```

Comment: The question asked for "most efficient", not "simple / straightforward".

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
    uint reverseMSBToLSB32ui(uint input)
    {
        uint output = 0x00000000;
        uint toANDVar = 0;
        int places = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            places = (32 - i);
            toANDVar = (uint)(1 << places);
            output |= (uint)(input & (toANDVar)) >> places;

        }


        return output;
    }
```

Small and easy (though, 32 bit only).

Comment: The question asked for "most efficient"; we can rule out looping 32 times.   (And especially not shifting the mask as well as having to shift the result down to the LSB)

Answer (score 1):

I thought this is one of the simplest way to reverse the bit. 
please let me know if there is any flaw in this logic. 
basically in this logic, we check the value of the bit in position.
set the bit if value is 1 on reversed position.

```
void bit_reverse(ui32 *data)
{
  ui32 temp = 0;    
  ui32 i, bit_len;    
  {    
   for(i = 0, bit_len = 31; i <= bit_len; i++)   
   {    
    temp |= (*data & 1 << i)? (1 << bit_len-i) : 0;    
   }    
   *data = temp;    
  }    
  return;    
}
```

Comment: The question asked for "most efficient", not "simple / straightforward".

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char ReverseBits(unsigned char data)
{
    unsigned char k = 0, rev = 0;

    unsigned char n = data;

    while(n)

    {
        k = n & (~(n - 1));
        n &= (n - 1);
        rev |= (128 / k);
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but division by a runtime variable is slow.  `k` is always a power of 2, but compilers probably won't prove that and turn it into bit-scan / shift.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method I know follows. `MSB` is input and `LSB` is 'reversed' output:

```
unsigned char rev(char MSB) {
    unsigned char LSB=0;  // for output
    _FOR(i,0,8) {
        LSB= LSB << 1;
        if(MSB&1) LSB = LSB | 1;
        MSB= MSB >> 1;
    }
    return LSB;
}

//    It works by rotating bytes in opposite directions. 
//    Just repeat for each byte.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Purpose: to reverse bits in an unsigned short integer 
// Input: an unsigned short integer whose bits are to be reversed
// Output: an unsigned short integer with the reversed bits of the input one
unsigned short ReverseBits( unsigned short a )
{
     // declare and initialize number of bits in the unsigned short integer
     const char num_bits = sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT;

     // declare and initialize bitset representation of integer a
     bitset<num_bits> bitset_a(a);          

     // declare and initialize bitset representation of integer b (0000000000000000)
     bitset<num_bits> bitset_b(0);                  

     // declare and initialize bitset representation of mask (0000000000000001)
     bitset<num_bits> mask(1);          

     for ( char i = 0; i < num_bits; ++i )
     {
          bitset_b = (bitset_b << 1) | bitset_a & mask;
          bitset_a >>= 1;
     }

     return (unsigned short) bitset_b.to_ulong();
}

void PrintBits( unsigned short a )
{
     // declare and initialize bitset representation of a
     bitset<sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT> bitset(a);

     // print out bits
     cout << bitset << endl;
}


// Testing the functionality of the code

int main ()
{
     unsigned short a = 17, b;

     cout << "Original: "; 
     PrintBits(a);

     b = ReverseBits( a );

     cout << "Reversed: ";
     PrintBits(b);
}

// Output:
Original: 0000000000010001
Reversed: 1000100000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another loop-based solution that exits quickly when the number is low (in C++ for multiple types)

```
template<class T>
T reverse_bits(T in) {
    T bit = static_cast<T>(1) << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1);
    T out;

    for (out = 0; bit && in; bit >>= 1, in >>= 1) {
        if (in & 1) {
            out |= bit;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

or in C for an unsigned int

```
unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int in) {
    unsigned int bit = 1u << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1);
    unsigned int out;

    for (out = 0; bit && in; bit >>= 1, in >>= 1) {
        if (in & 1)
            out |= bit;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that many other posts are concerned about speed (i.e best = fastest).
What about simplicity? Consider:

```
char ReverseBits(char character) {
    char reversed_character = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        char ith_bit = (c >> i) & 1;
        reversed_character |= (ith_bit << (sizeof(char) - 1 - i));
    }
    return reversed_character;
}
```

and hope that clever compiler will optimise for you.

If you want to reverse a longer list of bits (containing `sizeof(char) * n` bits), you can use this function to get:

```
void ReverseNumber(char* number, int bit_count_in_number) {
    int bytes_occupied = bit_count_in_number / sizeof(char);      

    // first reverse bytes
    for (int i = 0; i <= (bytes_occupied / 2); i++) {
        swap(long_number[i], long_number[n - i]);
    }

    // then reverse bits of each individual byte
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_occupied; i++) {
         long_number[i] = ReverseBits(long_number[i]);
    }
}
```

This would reverse [10000000, 10101010] into [01010101, 00000001].

Comment: You have 3 shifts in the inner loop.  Save one with `ith_bit = (c >> i) & 1`.  Also save a SUB by shifting `reversed_char` instead of shifting the bit, unless you're hoping it will compile on x86 to `sub something` / `bts reg,reg` to set the nth bit in the destination register.

Answer (score 0):

For other web-searchers who might encounter this question, here is a summary (for C and JavaScript).

For a complete solution in JavaScript, we can first [generate the table](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/bit-twiddle/blob/0c4c32db753108c5ec7e3779d35eb103be8e7ee1/twiddle.js#L115-L135):

```
const BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE = new Array(256)

for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
  var v = i, r = i, s = 7;
  for (v >>>= 1; v; v >>>= 1) {
    r <<= 1;
    r |= v & 1;
    --s;
  }
  BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[i] = (r << s) & 0xff;
}
```

This gives us `BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE`, which is what @MattJ posted:

```
const BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE = new Uint8Array([      
  0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xc0, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x60, 0xe0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xb0, 0x70, 0xf0, 
  0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xc8, 0x28, 0xa8, 0x68, 0xe8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xd8, 0x38, 0xb8, 0x78, 0xf8, 
  0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xa4, 0x64, 0xe4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xd4, 0x34, 0xb4, 0x74, 0xf4, 
  0x0c, 0x8c, 0x4c, 0xcc, 0x2c, 0xac, 0x6c, 0xec, 0x1c, 0x9c, 0x5c, 0xdc, 0x3c, 0xbc, 0x7c, 0xfc, 
  0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xc2, 0x22, 0xa2, 0x62, 0xe2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xd2, 0x32, 0xb2, 0x72, 0xf2, 
  0x0a, 0x8a, 0x4a, 0xca, 0x2a, 0xaa, 0x6a, 0xea, 0x1a, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0xda, 0x3a, 0xba, 0x7a, 0xfa,
  0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xc6, 0x26, 0xa6, 0x66, 0xe6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xd6, 0x36, 0xb6, 0x76, 0xf6, 
  0x0e, 0x8e, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x2e, 0xae, 0x6e, 0xee, 0x1e, 0x9e, 0x5e, 0xde, 0x3e, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0xfe,
  0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xc1, 0x21, 0xa1, 0x61, 0xe1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xd1, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x71, 0xf1,
  0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xc9, 0x29, 0xa9, 0x69, 0xe9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xd9, 0x39, 0xb9, 0x79, 0xf9, 
  0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x25, 0xa5, 0x65, 0xe5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xd5, 0x35, 0xb5, 0x75, 0xf5,
  0x0d, 0x8d, 0x4d, 0xcd, 0x2d, 0xad, 0x6d, 0xed, 0x1d, 0x9d, 0x5d, 0xdd, 0x3d, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0xfd,
  0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xc3, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x63, 0xe3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xd3, 0x33, 0xb3, 0x73, 0xf3, 
  0x0b, 0x8b, 0x4b, 0xcb, 0x2b, 0xab, 0x6b, 0xeb, 0x1b, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xdb, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0xfb,
  0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xc7, 0x27, 0xa7, 0x67, 0xe7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xd7, 0x37, 0xb7, 0x77, 0xf7, 
  0x0f, 0x8f, 0x4f, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xaf, 0x6f, 0xef, 0x1f, 0x9f, 0x5f, 0xdf, 0x3f, 0xbf, 0x7f, 0xff
])
```

Then the algorithms for 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit unsigned integers can be found [here](https://github.com/SySS-Research/syss-crc/blob/22d5c700d9827308046556f028910b73d72a8aca/syss_crc.py#L42-L84):

```
function reverseBits8(n) {
  return BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n]
}

function reverseBits16(n) {
  return (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >> 8) & 0xff] |
    BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n & 0xff] << 8)
}

function reverseBits32(n) {
  return (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n & 0xff] << 24) |
    (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >>> 8) & 0xff] << 16) |
    (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >>> 16) & 0xff] << 8) |
    BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >>> 24) & 0xff];
}
```

Note, the 32-bit version doesn't work in JavaScript (must convert to using BigInts which is straightforward), but should work in a 64-bit language:

```
log8(0b11000100)
log16(0b1110001001001100)
log32(0b11110010111110111100110010101011)

// 0b11000100 => 0b00100011
// 0b1110001001001100 => 0b0011001001000111
// doesn't work in JS it seems:
// 0b11110010111110111100110010101011 => 0b0-101010110011000010000010110001

function log8(n) {
  console.log(`${bits(n, 8)} => ${bits(reverseBits8(n), 8)}`)
}

function log16(n) {
  console.log(`${bits(n, 16)} => ${bits(reverseBits16(n), 16)}`)
}

function log32(n) {
  console.log(`${bits(n, 32)} => ${bits(reverseBits32(n), 32)}`)
}

function bits(n, size) {
  return `0b${n.toString(2).padStart(size, '0')}`
}
```

**Note:** This solution works in JavaScript for 32-bits:

```
function reverseBits32(n) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    res = (res << 1) + (n & 1);
    n = n >>> 1;
  }

  return res >>> 0;
}
```

**All 3 table based solutions will work fine in C.** Here is a rough C version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static uint8_t* BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE;

uint8_t* 
make_bit_reversal_table() {
  uint8_t *table = malloc(256 * sizeof(uint8_t));
  uint8_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < 256 ; ++i) {
    uint8_t v = i;
    uint8_t r = i;
    uint8_t s = 7;
    for (v = v >> 1; v; v = v >> 1) {
      r <<= 1;
      r |= v & 1;
      --s;
    }
    table[i] = (r << s) & 0xff;
  }
  return table;
}

uint8_t 
reverse_bits_8(uint8_t n) {
  return BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n];
}

uint16_t
reverse_bits_16(uint16_t n)
{
  return (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >> 8) & 0xff]
    | BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n & 0xff] << 8);
}

uint32_t
reverse_bits_32(uint32_t n) {
  return (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[n & 0xff] << 24) 
    | (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) 
    | (BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) 
    | BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE[(n >> 24) & 0xff];
}

int 
main(void) {
  BIT_REVERSAL_TABLE = make_bit_reversal_table();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit late to the party, I just tried to write my own 32bit unsigned integer bit reversal function using SSSE3. This seemed to be the most appropriate place to post it. I borrowed the non-SSSE3 code from Soonts' answer.

```
static inline uint32_t myreverseBits( uint32_t x ) {
#ifdef __SSSE3__
  __m128i lut = _mm_setr_epi8(
    0, 0x8, 0x4, 0xc,
    0x2, 0xa, 0x6, 0xe,
    0x1, 0x9, 0x5, 0xd,
    0x3, 0xb, 0x7, 0xf);
  union {
    __m128i sse;
    uint32_t u[4];
  } x128;
  x128.u[0] = (x >> 4) & 0xf0f0f0f; 
  x128.u[1] = x & 0xf0f0f0f;
  x128.sse = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lut, x128.sse);   // SSSE3 required
  x = x128.u[0] | (x128.u[1] << 4);
#else
    x = ( ( x & 0x55555555 ) << 1 ) | ( ( x & 0xAAAAAAAA ) >> 1 );
    x = ( ( x & 0x33333333 ) << 2 ) | ( ( x & 0xCCCCCCCC ) >> 2 );
    x = ( ( x & 0x0F0F0F0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( x & 0xF0F0F0F0 ) >> 4 );
#endif
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    return _byteswap_ulong( x );
#elif defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    return (uint32_t)_bswap( (int)x );
#else
    // Assuming gcc or clang
    return __builtin_bswap32( x );
#endif
}
```

Using intrinsics like this means that the compiler won't vectorise like it might if the usual scalar divide and conquer or similar method is used where multiple results can be computed in parallel. This function does otherwise perform favourably when called in series. Below are results for 100,000,000 calls which increment the result before using it again as the argument. It's from an old Westmere i5 laptop running Ubuntu, is compiled with gcc -O3 -msse4, and takes 12.9 cycles on average.

```
./bitreverse.bin 123123
17650035
reverseBits() Cycles = 1416933034 
17650035
brev_knuth() Cycles = 2283147714 
17650035
brev_classic() Cycles = 1593152280 
17650035
reverse() Cycles = 1655942366 
17650035
reverse256LUT() Cycles = 2373575237 
17650035
myreverseBits() Cycles = 1290444754
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline assembly in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char originalByte = 0xA3;
    unsigned char reversedByte;

__asm__(
    "movb %1, %%al\n\t"        // Load the byte into al
    "xorb %%ah, %%ah\n\t"      // Clear ah

    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"         // Start of unrolling
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"       
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"
    "ror $1, %%al\n\t"
    "adc %%ah, %%ah\n\t"       // End of unrolling

    "movb %%ah, %0\n\t"
    : "=r" (reversedByte)
    : "r" (originalByte)
    : "rax"
);

    printf("Original Byte: %x\n", originalByte); // 10100011
    printf("Reversed Byte: %x\n", reversedByte); // 11000101

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bit reversal in pseudo code

source -> byte to be reversed b00101100
 destination -> reversed, also needs to be of unsigned type so sign bit is not propogated down

copy into temp so original is unaffected, also needs to be of unsigned type so that sign bit is not shifted in automaticaly

```
bytecopy = b0010110
```

LOOP8:  //do this 8 times
    test if bytecopy is < 0 (negative)

```
    set bit8 (msb) of reversed = reversed | b10000000 

else do not set bit8

shift bytecopy left 1 place
bytecopy = bytecopy << 1 = b0101100 result

shift result right 1 place
reversed = reversed >> 1 = b00000000
8 times no then up^ LOOP8
8 times yes then done.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for 32 bit, we need to change the size if we consider 8 bits.

```
    void bitReverse(int num)
    {
        int num_reverse = 0;
        int size = (sizeof(int)*8) -1;
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(i=0,j=size;i<=size,j>=0;i++,j--)
        {
            if((num >> i)&1)
            {
                num_reverse = (num_reverse | (1<<j));
            }
        }
        printf("\n rev num = %d\n",num_reverse);
    }
```

Reading the input integer "num" in LSB->MSB order and storing in num_reverse in MSB->LSB order.

Comment: You should add an explanation to the code so that it is understood easier.

Answer (score -1):

My simple solution

```
BitReverse(IN)
    OUT = 0x00;
    R = 1;      // Right mask   ...0000.0001
    L = 0;      // Left mask    1000.0000...
    L = ~0; 
    L = ~(i >> 1);
    int size = sizeof(IN) * 4;  // bit size

    while(size--){
        if(IN & L) OUT = OUT | R; // start from MSB  1000.xxxx
        if(IN & R) OUT = OUT | L; // start from LSB  xxxx.0001
        L = L >> 1;
        R = R << 1; 
    }
    return OUT;
```

Comment: What's `i`?  Also, what's that magic constant `* 4`?  Is it `CHAR_BIT / 2`?