# Reverse bit pattern in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am converting a number to binary and have to use `putchar` to output each number.

The problem is that I am getting the order in reverse.

Is there anyway to reverse a numbers bit pattern before doing my own stuff to it?

As in int n has a specific bit pattern - how can I reverse this bit pattern?

Comment: Show us some code, at least the pseudo-code. Doing your homework is not right for us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient Algorithm for Bit Reversal (from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/efficient-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c)

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do this, some very fast. I had to look it up.

**Reverse bits in a byte**

```
b = ((b * 0x0802LU & 0x22110LU) | (b * 0x8020LU & 0x88440LU)) * 0x10101LU >> 16;
```

**Reverse an N-bit quantity in parallel in 5 * lg(N) operations:**

```
unsigned int v; // 32-bit word to reverse bit order

// swap odd and even bits
v = ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((v & 0x55555555) << 1);
// swap consecutive pairs
v = ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((v & 0x33333333) << 2);
// swap nibbles ... 
v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
// swap bytes
v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
// swap 2-byte long pairs
v = ( v >> 16             ) | ( v               << 16);
```

**Reverse bits in word by lookup table**

```
static const unsigned char BitReverseTable256[256] = 
{
#   define R2(n)     n,     n + 2*64,     n + 1*64,     n + 3*64
#   define R4(n) R2(n), R2(n + 2*16), R2(n + 1*16), R2(n + 3*16)
#   define R6(n) R4(n), R4(n + 2*4 ), R4(n + 1*4 ), R4(n + 3*4 )
    R6(0), R6(2), R6(1), R6(3)
};

unsigned int v; // reverse 32-bit value, 8 bits at time
unsigned int c; // c will get v reversed

// Option 1:
c = (BitReverseTable256[v & 0xff] << 24) | 
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) | 
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) |
    (BitReverseTable256[(v >> 24) & 0xff]);

// Option 2:
unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *) &v;
unsigned char * q = (unsigned char *) &c;
q[3] = BitReverseTable256[p[0]]; 
q[2] = BitReverseTable256[p[1]]; 
q[1] = BitReverseTable256[p[2]]; 
q[0] = BitReverseTable256[p[3]];
```

Please look at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel for more information and references.

Comment: nice way of building lookup table

Answer (score 5):

Pop bits off your input and push them onto your output. Multiplying and dividing by 2 are the push and pop operations. In pseudo-code:

```
reverse_bits(x) {
    total = 0
    repeat n times {
       total = total * 2
       total += x % 2 // modulo operation
       x = x / 2
    }
    return total
}
```

See [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) on Wikipedia if you haven't seen this operator.

Further points:

- What would happen if you changed 2 to 4? Or to 10?
- How does this effect the value of n? What is n?
- How could you use bitwise operators (`<<`, `>>`, `&`) instead of divide and modulo? Would this make it faster?
- Could we use a different algorithm to make it faster? Could lookup tables help?

Comment: +1 - Just what I was trying to say but couldn't type as quickly and succintly.

Comment: If too slow, `x % 2` is equivalent to `x & 1`.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: AFAIK, such optimizations rarely help these days; compilers are good enough to figure that much out. _Au contraire_, `x ^= x;` might actually be a slower thing on modern machines, considering the fact that some chip designers (Intel, IIRC), so used to seeing `x = 0` rearranged the assembly instructions higher up than that for the corresponding xor operation, to speed things up.

Comment: You may want to code up something in assembly language.  Many processors have good, specialized, bit instructions.  The useful instruction is Rotate Into Carry and Rotate Carry In.  This enables the carry bit as a temporary storage.

Comment: @dirkgently. See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545844/biggest-performance-improvement-youve-had-with-the-smallest-change/1030546#1030546

Comment: This is the easy way, not an efficient way though. If it's just a few characters, then ok. If you need to swap megabytes or more, look for a more efficient (but less readable) way.

Comment: @Adriaan: See my comments under the code. Optimizing for speed is left as a homework exercise. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: you have a loop that prints the 0th bit (n&1), then shifts the number right. Instead, write a loop that prints the 31st bit (n&0x80000000) and shifts the number left. Before you do that loop, do another loop that shifts the number left until the 31st bit is 1; unless you do that, you'll get leading zeros.

Reversing is possible, too. Somthing like this:

```
unsigned int n = 12345; //Source
unsigned int m = 0; //Destination
int i;
for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
    m |= n&1;
    m <<= 1;
    n >>= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know: that is not exactly C, but I think that is an interesting answer:

```
int reverse(int i) {
  int output;
  __asm__(
     "nextbit:"
        "rcll $1, %%eax;"
        "rcrl $1, %%ebx;"
        "loop nextbit;"
        : "=b" (output)
        : "a" (i), "c" (sizeof(i)*8) );
  return output;
}
```

The rcl opcode puts the shifted out bit in the carry flag, then rcr recovers that bit to another register in the reverse order.

Comment: this implies x86, which may not necessarily be true. And even on x86 it's less efficient than many other solutions

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a integer and you're attempting to convert it to binary?

And the "answer" is ABCDEFG, but your "answer" is GFEDCBA?

If so, I'd double check the endian of the machine you're doing it on and the machine the "answer" came from.

Answer (score 0):

Here are functions I've used to reverse bits in a byte and reverse bytes in a quad.

```
inline unsigned char reverse(unsigned char b) {
    return (b&1 << 7)
         | (b&2 << 5)
         | (b&4 << 3)
         | (b&8 << 1)
         | (b&0x10 >> 1)
         | (b&0x20 >> 3)
         | (b&0x40 >> 5)
         | (b&0x80 >> 7);
}

inline unsigned long wreverse(unsigned long w) {
    return ( ( w     &0xFF) << 24)
         | ( ((w>>8) &0xFF) << 16)
         | ( ((w>>16)&0xFF) << 8)
         | ( ((w>>24)&0xFF) );
}
```

Comment: Those types of ternary evaluations can be quite slow, and should probably be avoided in high-performance scenarios.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I'm replacing it with shifts. That "optimal" answer scares me.