# Reverse bits in number

Tags: java

For example, I have the binary number 1011 which is equal to decimal 11. I want the reverse bit's location such that it become 1101, which is decimal 13. Here is code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class bits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter x:");
        int x=scnr.nextInt();
        int b=0;
        while (x!=0){
            b|=( x &1);
            x>>=1;
            b<<=1;
        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

But when I enter x 11 then it prints 26. What is the mistake?

Comment: a full Integer can be reversed with `Integer.reverse(int i)` - but as it looks like you want to reverse integers with less bits, I leave it as a comment.

Comment: looks like the solution is already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c
You are missing that there needs to be an extra shift needed at end

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are shifting `b` one time too many. Do the shift first (so that the first time, when `b == 0`, it has no effect):

```
while (x!=0){
  b<<=1;
  b|=( x &1);
  x>>=1;
}
```

Comment: What if we also want to consider the padding? 1011 is actually 00001011 so the reverse must be 10110000

Comment: Then you can use a `for` loop that does a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: You replied to a 11 year old thread! Damn! 
Also, yeah I did that! Thank you!! I maintained a count and then did b<<=(8-count)

Comment: Can't resist that red notification counter ;)

Answer (score 16):

Slightly offtopic.  There's also the option of the built-in bit reversing features of Java.

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse(int)

EDIT: This assumes you're using Java 1.5 or newer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `>>>=` instead of `>>=`
2. If you want to change method signature to `public static byte reverse(byte in)` this will not work on negative values because there is implicit cast to int.

Answer (score 2):

The program do not work for input like 1, 2

```
int reverseBits(int x)
    {
        int b = 0;
        while (x != 0)
        {
            b <<= 1;
            b |= ( x & 1);
            x >>= 1
        }
        return b;
    }
```

input 1 output 1, should be 8 right?
input 2 output 1, should be 4.

Answer (score 2):

Note for beginners: I use hexadecimal (0-9 and A-F) because one hexadecimal digit maps to 4 binary bits perfectly. Instead of writing 1010, I use A (10 decimal).  You can tell Java to use hexadecimal (literals) by starting with 0x as in 0x0A.

As stated before, 1 should output 8  (0001 to 1000).
So instead of while(x!=0), the code needs to shift the first bit as far as the length of the bits needed in this example it is 4.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { // not while (x!=0){
   b<<=1;
   b|=( x &1);
   x>>=1;
}
Hex convert 0-F: 0=0 1=8 2=4 3=C 4=2 5=A 6=6 7=E 8=1 9=9 A=5 B=D C=3 D=B E=7 F=F
```

Or full 8 bit example:

```
public static byte reverse(byte x) {
    byte b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        b<<=1;
        b|=( x &1);
        x>>=1;
      }
    return b;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte[] nums = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
            (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0xFF };
    for (byte b : nums) {
        System.out.printf("%02X=%02X ", b, reverse(b));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
00=00 01=80 02=40 03=C0 04=20 05=A0 06=60 07=E0 08=10
09=90 0A=50 0B=D0 0C=30 0D=B0 0E=70 0F=F0 10=08 11=88 AA=55 FE=7F FF=FF
```

Answer (score 1):

b is shifted left once too often. I expect input 1 to result in output 2. Move the Shift two lines up.

Answer (score 1):

you shifted b once too many. try shifting b to the left before doing the |=:

```
    while (x!=0){
           b<<=1;
           b|=( x &1);
           x>>=1;

         }
   System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're left shifting `b` one time more than required. Add `b >>= 1` after your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(x!=0){
    b<<=1;
    b|=(x&1);
    x>>=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is twice as much as expected so the last left shift operation (one left shift doubles the value) is too much.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to use the unsigned right shift operator (>>>) in the while loop to obviate the danger of running into an infinite loop for -ve numbers.

```
while (x!=0){
  b<<=1;
  b|=( x &1);
  x>>>=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My new java code reverse bits in an integer using java with powerful bit manipulation. It is working with positive, negative and zero values. Hope it helps.

```
public static int  reverseDigits(int num) throws Exception {
        if (num == 0) {         
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE | Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        int count = Integer.SIZE * 8 - 1;
        int  reversed = num;        
        boolean positive = true;

        if (num < 0) {
            positive = false;
        }

        if (positive) num >>= 1;

        while(num != 0) {

            reversed <<= 1; 
            reversed |= (num & 1);          

            num >>>= 1;
            count--;            
        }

        if (positive) reversed <<= count;
        return reversed;
    }
```

You can represent bits in integer with my other bit manipulation code in java what print zeroes on the left:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39056535/6738542

Because Integer.toBinaryString() will hide the zeroes on the left.

Metal |,,|

Comment: much nicer if you use this line: boolean positive = (num < 0) ? false : true;
and forget the next if statement.

Comment: "throws Exception" is not important, I used it only for other tests.

Comment: or `boolean positive = num>=0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
//    i/p=3 
//    o/p=3221225472
// Clearly observe the 1L while doing the left shift, if ignored it will fail to return the expected output dur to mismatch in bit size.

    public static long reverse(long n) {
        long rev = 0;
        for(int i = 31; i >=0; i--){
            if((n & 1<<i) != 0){
                rev = rev | 1L<<(31-i);
            }
        }
        return rev;
    }
```