# Print a short in binary format in Java

Tags: java, binary, short

Is there any builtin support for outputting a binary representation of a short in java?

There is of course, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java), which recommends the use of Integer.toBinaryString(), which works.  There is no comparable Short.toBinaryString().  Is anything else available?

**Update:**
Integer.toBinaryString() doesn't quite work the way Short.toBinaryString() would work if it existed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Short.MIN_VALUE));
}
```

produces

```
11111111111111111000000000000000
```

whereas I would like to see

```
1000000000000000
```

Of course, it's easy enough to chop off the first 16 digits, but that's kind of my point.  This method ought to exist.

Answer (score 9):

All shorts can be safely cast to integers, so the linked answer will work fine as long as you correctly convert the `short` value to `int` before making the conversion (and in doing so, we're making sure that the digits at the beginning are zeroed):

```
short x = 10;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xFFFF & x));
=> 1010

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xFFFF & Short.MIN_VALUE));
=> 1000000000000000
```

To put it another way: all `short`s *are* integers, so there's no need to define a separate method for obtaining the binary representation of a `short`.

Comment: @SteveCohen right you are. A bit of fiddling is required, see my updated answer

Comment: Well, with that amendment I'll call it good.  There's nothing better.  I wish the inventors of java hadn't been so quick to dismiss unsigneds.

Comment: @SteveCohen agreed, they did it to simplify the language, but unsigned values are useful enough and they should have been a part of the language

Comment: heh, just try interoperating with legacy C.  :-)  Welcome to my world.