# Get bits from Java long as String

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, long-integer

How to get all 64 bits of a long as a String in Java?

So I want to do something like this -

```
long value = 10;
String bits = getBits(value);
System.out.println(bits);
```

I suppose the output would be

```
0000...1010 (64 bits)
```

And no, this is not homework! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Long.toString` with the radix:

```
String bits = Long.toString(someLong, 2);
```

2 specifies binary as opposed to any other base.

Edit: If you want to left-pad:

```
String bits = Long.toString(someLong, 2);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int toPrepend=10-str.length(); toPrepend>0; toPrepend--) {
    sb.append('0');
}
sb.append(bits);
String output = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call the method for it:

```
Long.toBinaryString(long number)
```