# Counting the binary in a number java?

Tags: java, binary

I'm new to java and am wondering if there is any way to count the actual number of ones and zeros in the binary of a single int. For example, I would try and find out the number of 1's and zero's in the binary   32 bit binary of int 6?

Comment: Do it the same way you would in any other language you know and wrap the logic in a `main()` in a class.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263199/3802841 to see how an int can be formatted as a string. Count either the '0's or the '1' and substract the count from the length of the string.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`Integer.bitcount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)):

```
int ones = Integer.bitCount(n);
int zeros = Integer.bitCount(~n) - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
```

Comment: Good job giving away the answer. Great help for the OP

Comment: Awesome. Who would have thought they'd already implemented this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)

Comment: @xgeorgekx Good job at answering the question? Thank you.

Comment: @xgeorgekx: You're going to downvote all the answers but yours? Really?

Comment: I do not see any constructive answers. Anyone can just paste the code.

Comment: I have implemented this and for an n value of 36 Integer.bitCount(~n) returns 30 somehow...

Does it flip all of the bits that an integer could contain o.O?

Comment: Well, the question is: "Is there any way to count the actual number of ones and zeros in the binary of a single int". Yes there is using this method. What is there to explain?

Comment: @LanguidSquid Yes, I edited to avoid having ``zeros = 32 - ones``

Comment: That's neat! Thanks, I didn't know about that utility on Integer

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, java has a built in method: Integer.toBinaryString()
This takes an integer value, converts it to binary, then returns it as a String.

Or you could brush up on your java skills and create your own method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you provide no code i will give some guildines on how you can do it.

1. Get the binary represesantation of your `int` by calling this method `Integer.toBinaryString(x);`
2. The previous method will return only the nessecery bits of the number for example in the case of `6` it will return `110`. But you need a 32 bit representation of 6 so you have to add the extra zeros in front of the result returned from that method.
3. create 2 counter variables. One for ones and one for zeros.
4. loop through the characters of your `String` and when a `char == 0` increment the zeros counter. When `char == 1` increment the ones counter.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why convert to ``String`` while the bits are *right there*, inside the ``int``?