# Adding binary numbers Java

Tags: java, addition, calculator

I need to add binary numbers in Java. I tried on this way as below is written, the result is correct, but result is decimal number. Does anyone know how to get result as binary number?

Thanks in advance

```
private int number2;
private int number2;
private int result;

number1 = Byte.parseByte(String.valueOf(display.getText()));
number2 = Byte.parseByte(String.valueOf(display.getText()));
result = getDecimalFromBinary(number1) + getDecimalFromBinary(number2);
display.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

Comment: How are you distinguishing what you consider to be a "binary number" and what you consider to be a "decimal number"?

Comment: *Binary numbers* contains 0 and 1. *Decimal numbers* contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) what you are looking for?

Comment: @silent_rain I don't think you are getting my point. You have a number inside a computer. It will generally be represented in binary - even BigDecimal does not actually store strings of [0,9]. What do you require to make you consider something a decimal number?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Hm, I am not sure. I tried to convert binary to decimal, Integer.toBinaryString() but it doesn't work...

Comment: Integer.toBinaryString() takes the internal, binary, representation of a number and outputs it as a string of zeros and ones. In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: It gives me result in decimal.. For example, when I put 11+11, I get 6 as result.. It is true, 11+11=110 (110=6 in decimal). But, I need binary as result, I need to get 110 not 6...

Comment: Well, your code works for me. I used `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number1), 2)` as a replacement for your `getDecimalFromBinary(number1)`, but I get the expected result.

Comment: I tried now also with 'Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number1), 2)' , but I get 6 as result again...

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));`?

Comment: @Tom On my calculator I get 6. but as output of 'System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));' I get 110... hm, it is wierd..

Comment: Then `display.setText(...)` seems to be the problem. Is `display` a `JTextField`?

Comment: @Tom Yes, it is JTextField...

Comment: @Tom Do you suppose what it can be?

Comment: Well, even with a `JTextField` it works for me. Can you try to build a small program which demonstrates that problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print an integer in binary format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java)

Comment: @Tom The program is big, I make advanced calculator... The only problem is this part of code where I need to display binary numbers... I tried to solve it in many ways, but the result is the same.. As output, I get binary, but on my display I get decimal number....

Comment: But, when I put result in other JTextField, it works.... I don't know what it can be,.. maybe some settings for JTextField i changet to forbid binary numbers....

Comment: If you change the values of the source numbers, do you get the correct result in decimal? Or always *6*? Is there maybe another part of code, which writes to that JTextField?

Comment: Maybe this part of code is not correct: 
'if (result > -100000000 && result < 100000000) {
                display1.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
            } else {
                display1.setText("Error");
            }'

Comment: Try to find each place where you set the textfield, set a brakepoint there and check which one sets the value to *6*. Might be time-consuming, but it might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example seems to be incomplete, because [`Integer.parseInt(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) and [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) are what you need. Perhaps you aren't storing `result` as a `String`. For example,

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("11", 2);
int b = Integer.parseInt("11", 2);
String result = Integer.toBinaryString(a + b)
System.out.println(result);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
110
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... but, i tried this, and stored result as String but I get 6 again... I don't know why is it...

Comment: Note that an `int` is always stored in binary. So do `long`, `float`, `double`. `BigDecimal` is not, and stored in it's base 10 form or decimal form. By default, when converting an `int` to a `String`, it will be transformed using base 10 (decimal form, or 0-9 characters). To store it as a `String` in it's binary form (1 and 0 characters), you always have to call the `Integer.toBinaryString` as shown on this answer.