# Convert decimal number into Binary Format Using Java

Tags: java, binary

Is this correct? I am trying to set this up as an interview question and need help with the correct answer. If anyone can take a look at the code below and let me know if this is the correct answer, and if there are other correct answers than just the one below that would be great.

The question is "Create a Program That Will Convert Decimal Number into Binary Format" Using JAVA

```
package com.java2novice.algos;

public class DecToBin {

    public void showBinaryFormat(int numbers){
        int binaryNo[] = new int[25];
        int indexNo = 0;
        while(number > 0){
            binaryNo[index++] = numbers%2;
            numbers = numbers/2;
        }
        for(int i = indexNo-1;i >= 0;i--){
            System.out.print(binaryNo[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        DecimalToBinary dtb = new DecimalToBinary();
        dtb.showBinaryFormat(25);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Is this correct?** - Run it, test it and you'll know if it's correct. Instead, if you have any specific error paste it in the question with the complete stacktrace. I see at least one compilation problem here.

Comment: You could get help from codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What @BackSlash said, plus `indexNo` and `index` are not the same variable.

Comment: I will tell you right now it is not correct: you have `while (number > 0) {` but `number` is undefined

Comment: @svasa: The OP should still determine if it works first.  We're not responsible for determining that.

Comment: Which binary format are you trying to represent? Java uses 2's complement for integers, they're also 32 bit (not 25), you seem to be storing 25 bit unsigned integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print an integer in binary format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will be easier to use `toBinaryString` method from `Integer` class e.g:

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(someIntValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is mostly correct. But you mistyped some of the names of the variables. For example, you typed `index` when you actually mean `indexNo`. I have corrected them for you:

```
public void showBinaryFormat(int numbers){
    int binaryNo[] = new int[25];
    int indexNo = 0;
    while(numbers > 0){
        binaryNo[indexNo++] = numbers%2;
        numbers = numbers/2;
    }
    for(int i = indexNo-1;i >= 0;i--){
        System.out.print(binaryNo[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that your code can only 25 bit unsigned integers.

Alternative solutions, well, you can add `static` to the `showBinaryFormat` method so you can call it more conveniently. Or just be lazy and use `Integer.toBinaryString()` instead.