# I created decimal to binary method and I want to use it in 2D array but I can't

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I created simple decimal to binary method like this :

```
public static int[] convertDectoB(int number, int size) {
    int binary[] = new int[size];
    for (int a = number; a > 0 && size > 0; size--, a = a / 2) {
        binary[size - 1] = a % 2;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

I asked user to enter numbers like that :

"Enter numbers : "

4-2-7.

The aim is convert these 3 numbers into a binary and print it :

1 0 0

0 1 0

1 1 1

I also created numberFinder method to extract integers into the String that user entered :

```
public static int[] numberFinder(String numbers, int size) {
    int numaraa[] = new int[size];
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numaraa.length; i++) {
        for (; a < numbers.length(); a++) {
            if (numbers.charAt(i) == '-')
                i++;
            else if (a == 0) {
                if (Character.isDigit(numbers.charAt(a)))
                    numaraa[i] += numbers.charAt(a);
            }
            else {
                if (Character.isDigit(numbers.charAt(a)))
                    numaraa[i] += numbers.charAt(a);
            }
        }
    }
    return numaraa;
}
```

In the end , I created 2D array and I wanna implement these binary values :

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainarray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mainarray[i].length; j++) {
            mainarray[i][j] = ? 
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't implement all binary values for each array block.

Comment: For your `numberFinder`, you can use `string.split("-")` instead.

Comment: Integer::toBinaryString() should work if your aim is to print the values.

Comment: "MWB" ty for your advice but we did not learned split method in the class so I can't use it.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use ready methods like toBinaryString(). We have to create our own methods to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make your own `toBinaryString()` method there are a lot of examples online, such as borrowing the logic from this answer [Print an integer in binary format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639411/1248974):

```
public static String intToString(int number) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 2; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            int mask = 1 << i;
            result.append((number & mask) != 0 ? "1" : "0");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Note: I modified this method to only hold 3 digit binary codes, so the highest integer it can convert is `7`. However if you want to convert larger integers, say up to 16, or 32, you'll need to increase the counter in the `for`-loop, which I'll leave that for you to decide.

For each line in the user input, split it on the hyphen character `'-'`:

```
codes = line.split("-");
ListofCourses.addAll(Arrays.asList(codes));
...
```

Then call this method on your `ListofCourses`:

```
for(int r = 0; r < ListofCourses.size(); r++){
    System.out.println(intToString(Integer.parseInt(ListofCourses.get(r))));
}
ListofCourses.clear();
```

Then should get expected output. Here's demo:

```
Ron's Copy

Enter 3 collections of course codes one collection per line
4-2-7

Size: 3 Sorted: [4, 2, 7]
100
010
111
```