# Could anybody explain this bit operations?

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift

```
Decimal         Binary 

x1 = 105        0110 1001
x2 = -38        1101 1010  

1. (byte) (x>>2) 
2. (byte) (x>>>26)
```

I understand the first shift will shift it two times to the right, and replace the missing bits with a 1. so the shift results in:
1111 0110

but I have no idea why the second shifts results in: 
0011 1111 or 63.

My understanding is that the x >> adds 1 if x is negative and adds a 0 if x is positive. The >>> adds a 0 regardless of the sign. So if that is the case wouldn't the result of x2 >>> 26 be 0000 0000?

Comment: `(byte) (x>>>26)` first shifts, then casts to `byte`. What type was `x`? I bet it was wider than 8 bits.

Comment: Might help. [Bitwise Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-shift-operators-in-java/)  as @FedericoklezCulloca said; you may want to experiment with using an int to hold the correct value. I found casting variables to be tricky even when trying to write high performance networking when I first started trying bit shifting..

Comment: x2 is a byte also

Comment: Ok, please fix your example (including types for `x1` and `x2` and placing the correct thing instead of `x` in the shifts.

Comment: Please also take a look at [Stackoverflow Printing Bits Representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java) this may help you debug whats happening with your bit shifts. EDIT: I personally use @M2X answer.

Comment: I don't think the types matter, because the values are widened to 32 bit (`int`) before the shift anyway. I. e. -38 isn't `1101 1010` here, but `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 1010`. Which should make it clear why `-38 >>> 26` is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1111` (63).

Comment: Since you'll edit your question anyway, can you plaese provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that is, a small program that shows what your problem is).

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the "strange" bit shift result is because the values are *widened* to 32 bit (`int`) *before* the shift.

I. e. `-38` isn't `1101 1010` here, but `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 1010`.

Which should make it clear why `-38 >>> 26` is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1111` (or `63`).

The widening is described in the the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1):

> Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int` by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

---

If you want to perform bit shift operations on an 8 bit (`byte`) value, you could *mask* the value to use only the lower 8 bits, after widening but before shifting, like Federico suggests:

```
byte x = -38;
(x & 0xFF) >>> 26;
```

This would give the expected value of 0 (though I'm not sure if it makes sense, as any 8 bit value will be 0 if you right shift by more than 8).

Comment: If `x` is a `byte` you would probably want `(x & 0xFF) >>> 26`, but yes, it would make the result 0, if that is the goal.

Comment: Sorry, I got carried away with the `F`s. Anyway, yes, I think that's what they're trying to achieve. By "solve the problem" I meant "give the expected result".

Comment: thanks all! it's not a program per say, it's more of practice exercise in using bit operators. why is -38 represented as  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 1010?@haraldK

Comment: @blondiefunk69 If this is indeed an exercise, I'll leave it to you to figure that out. Here's some suggested reading though: [Two's complenent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). ;-)