# In what format is data sent on, getInputStream on a URLconnection Object?

Tags: java, url

Im trying to connect to a `php` script on a server and retrieve the text the script echoes.Do accomplish I used the following code.

CODE:=

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class con{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        int c;
        URL tj = new URL("http://www.thejoint.cf/test.php");
        URLConnection tjcon = tj.openConnection();
        InputStream input = tjcon.getInputStream();
        while(((c = input.read()) != -1)){
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        input.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Caught this Exception:"+e);
    }
    }
}
```

I do get the desired output that is the text "You will be Very successful".But when I remove the `(char)` type casting it yields a 76 digit long. 
`8911111732119105108108329810132118101114121321151179999101115115102117108108`
number which I'm not able to make sense of.I read that the `getInputStream` is a `byte stream`, then should there be number of digits times 8 number long output?
Any insight would be very helpful, Thank you

Comment: Oh I thought it would give out the `byte` representation of the individual letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not print one number 76 digits long. You have a loop there, it prints a lot of numbers, each up to three digits long (one byte).

In ASCII, 89 = "Y", 111 = "o"  ....

What the cast to `char` that you removed did was that it interpreted that number as a Unicode code point and printed the corresponding characters instead (also one at a time).

This way of reading text byte by byte is very fragile. It basically only works with ASCII. You should be using a `Reader` to wrap the `InputStream`. Then you can read `char` and `String` directly (and it will take care of character sets such as Unicode).

> Oh I thought it would give out the byte representation of the individual letter.

But that's exactly what it does.
You can see it more clearly if you use `println` instead of `print` (then it will print each number on its own line).

Comment: Thank You sir..!, and what I meant by byte is the binary representation of the individual letter.

Comment: Ah, you mean bits? Those are of course all present in the `byte`, but not normally printed as eight bits, but as a decimal or (most frequent) in hex (such as `0x6E`). You could, if you want, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/print-an-integer-in-binary-format-in-java