# Reversing Bits in F#

Tags: f#, bit

I need help reversing bits in F# as done in this question [Reverse bits in number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165776/reverse-bits-in-number?newreg=e63adb022d8c4be1ab58adad0820421f). I'm new to F# and was wondering how we can do this?

```
let bitreverse x = 
   let mutable b = 0
       while x do 
          b >>>= 1
          b|= x & 1
          x >>>= 1
b
```

I'm not even sure the syntax is correct here. I am very knew to this language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show what you have tried and what exactly did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct translation into F# looks like this:

```
let bitreverse x = 
    let mutable x = x
    let mutable b = 0
    while x <> 0 do 
        b <- b <<< 1
        b <- b ||| (x &&& 1)
        x <- x >>> 1
    b
```

This is highly imperative with mutable values and this isn't usually how we'd tend to go about writing code in F#.  Notice that re-assignment of a mutable variable is a little different to what you might be used to in an imperative language, you have to use `<-` which is called the destructive update operator.

Thankfully, it's pretty straightforward to translate this into a recursive function that uses immutable values which should be a little more idiomatic

```
let bitreverse2 x =
    let rec bitRerverseHelper b x =
        match x with
        |0 -> b // if 0, the recursion stops here and we return the result: b
        |_ -> bitRerverseHelper ((b <<< 1) ||| (x &&& 1)) (x >>> 1) // otherwise recurse
    bitRerverseHelper 0 x
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a shorter way to reverse bits than this?

Comment: @user112901 Kind of, you could use `if` instead of pattern matching to put the logic on one line, e.g. `let rec bitRerverseHelper b x = if x = 0 then b else bitRerverseHelper ((b <<< 1) ||| (x &&& 1)) (x >>> 1)`.  I find the pattern matching easier to read though.

Comment: I meant like is there another completely different way to reverse bits in F#? Like builtin functions, or any other logic that may be simpler/shorter than this logic?

Comment: @user112901 Not built-in, no.  This answer has a pretty thorough overview of some possible approaches, albeit described in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/746203/5438433 so you could certainly go shorter for a data type smaller than `int.`

Answer (score 3):

1. F# doesn't support compound assignment, so you can't do something like `b |= x & 1`, you need to expand it to `b <- b ||| (x &&& 1)`.
2. The argument `x` isn't mutable, so you need to create a local binding and mutate that.  It looks weird, but you can just write `let mutable x = x` as the first line of your function to shadow the existing binding with a mutable one.
3. `x` is an int, not a bool, so you can't use it as the condition for your while loop.  Use `x <> 0` instead.
4. Indentation matters in F#, so make sure that `while` and your final `b` both line up with the first `let`.

Fixing those issues will make your code work, but idiomatic F# would probably forgo the `while` loop and mutation and use a recursive inner function with an accumulator instead.