# LSB to MSB bit reversal on ARM

Tags: arm, bit-manipulation, neon

I need to reverse an YUV image with each byte in LSB instead of MSB. I have read [Best Algorithm for Bit Reversal ( from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c) but I would like to do something that is ARM-optimized.

```
int8 *image;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    image[i] = reversebit8(image[i]); //Use the lookup mechanism
}
```

As I control the image format (two-byte YUYV or any permutation), I would be OK to reverse 16 bits:

```
int16 *image;
for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
    image[i] = reversebit16(image[i]);
}
```

Image goes from YUYV LSB to UYVY MSB. Or even in 32 bits:

```
int32 *image;
for(i = 0; i < size / 4; i++) {
    image[i] = reversebit32(image[i]);
}
```

Image goes from YUYV LSB to VYUY MSB.

Question: How can I do that in an optimized way for ARM? Neon is good too.

I think that those instructions http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihjgdid.htm could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned it in my question, those ARM instructions (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihjgdid.htm) can do the trick:

```
int32 *image;
for (i = 0; i < size / 4; h++) {
    asm("rbit %1,%0" : "=r" (image[i]) : "r" (image[i]));
    asm("rev %1,%0" : "=r" (image[i]) : "r" (image[i]));
}
```

rbit reverses the 32 bits, bit by bit. rev reverses the 32 bits, byte by byte. In fine, each byte is reversed independently. I'm still wondering if there is a better syntax or a better way to do this.

Comment: You do not need to loop for 8bit and 16 bit values.   I think that `rbit` followed by either `rev` or a 16 bit rotate will reverse *packed* 8bit and 16bit values.  For 32bits, just the `rbit` is needed.

Comment: Attention! Source %0 and destination %1 have wrong order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870180/1611317

Answer (score 6):

The ARM `RBIT` instruction does what you want.  Write a loop that calls this on every aligned 4-byte value.

```
A8.6.134 RBIT
Reverse Bits reverses the bit order in a 32-bit register. Encoding T1 ARMv6T2, ARMv7

RBIT<c> <Rd>,<Rm>

if ConditionPassed() then
   EncodingSpecificOperations(); bits(32) result;
   for i = 0 to 31 do
      result<31-i> = R[m]<i>;
   R[d] = result;
```