# Equivalent of De Bruijn LSB, but for MSB

Tags: bit-manipulation

Does anyone know of an algorithm similar to De Bruijn's LSB, but for MSB? Or alternately the most efficient way of determining the MSB?

I know Log_2(Val) will do this, but I don't know if it's the most efficient method.

The reason I need it is I need to convert little-endian to big-endian. I know the standard algorithm for this. However, the input is 64 bit, but typically the numbers will be 16 or 24 bit, so swapping the whole 8 bytes around is unneeded 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c helpful?

Comment: I'd be surprised if special-casing this kind of thing would give a performance win - byte swapping is only a few instructions, so adding a few more instructions to test for special cases may well be counter-productive, particularly if you have branching.

Comment: @Jeff that is helpful, thanks. @Paul, you could be right. However, I also have the need of knowing how many bytes to process.

Comment: I'm thinking a simple loop: test with AND, << test by 8 pattern will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this exactly http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn ?

Comment: I don't understand:  for `0x110`, this gives 12, which is MSB.  LSB would be 4.

Comment: @IanC: @AShelly is right. http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightMultLookup gets LSB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast method and are able/willing to use hardware specific instructions, you should take a look at x86 **BSR** (Bit Scan Reverse) or similar instruction.

> Searches the source operand (second operand) for the most significant set bit (1 bit). If a most significant 1 bit is
>   found, its bit index is stored in the destination operand (first operand).

```
xor edx, edx
mov eax, 0x12345678
bsr edx, eax
```

It should store 28 in edx (bit 28 is the MSB). edx would be unchanged if no MSB is found.