# Reversing bits of Python integer

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation

Given a decimal integer (eg. 65), how does one reverse the underlying bits in Python? i.e.. the following operation:

```
65 → 01000001 → 10000010 → 130
```

It seems that this task can be broken down into three steps:

1. Convert the decimal integer to binary representation
2. Reverse the bits
3. Convert back to decimal

Steps #2 and 3 seem pretty straightforward (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333509/how-do-you-reverse-the-significant-bits-of-an-integer-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c) SO question related to step #2), but I'm stuck on step #1. The issue with step #1 is retrieving the full decimal representation with filling zeros (ie. 65 = 01000001, not 1000001).

I've searched around, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: For step one, you can use `str(bin(65))[2:].zfill(8)`. To lazy/tired to look further into this now. But you should probably just do as larsmans says.

Comment: "The issue with step #1 is retrieving the full decimal representation with filling zeros (ie. 65 = 01000001, not 1000001)." **Why should it** be `01000001` and not `1000001`? **Why shouldn't it be** `00000000000000000000000001000001` (32 bits) instead? Or any other arbitrary number of bits?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
int('{:08b}'.format(n)[::-1], 2)
```

You can specify any filling length in place of the 8. If you want to get really fancy,

```
b = '{:0{width}b}'.format(n, width=width)
int(b[::-1], 2)
```

lets you specify the width programmatically.

Comment: Elegant and concise.  I needed to change the format string to `'{:08b}'` to work as specified.

Comment: Ah, yes, he wanted the filling zeroes. I'll amend.

Comment: If I do `int('{:b}'.format(65)[::-1], 2)`, I just get `65` as output. Using `{:08b}` instead of `{:b}` gives the correct result though, so +1 for elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Slight reading comprehension fail, answer amended.

Comment: @nneonneo & Shane, thanks to both of you. I read up on `format()` and this makes a lot sense. Definitely the most elegant solution.

Comment: Didn't understand [::-1] portion, Can someone explain please ?

Comment: This is list slicing which causes iterating the list in the reverse order.

Answer (score 16):

If you are after more speed, you can use the technique described in
[http://leetcode.com/2011/08/reverse-bits.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226083354/http://leetcode.com/2011/08/reverse-bits.html)

```
def reverse_mask(x):
    x = ((x & 0x55555555) << 1) | ((x & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1)
    x = ((x & 0x33333333) << 2) | ((x & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2)
    x = ((x & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | ((x & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4)
    x = ((x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) | ((x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8)
    x = ((x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16) | ((x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)
    return x
```

Comment: FYI: the link is now broken. Is this function limited to ints or will it work on numbers of type bignum?

Comment: Since the link is broken, the same procedure can be found here with a bit more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002555/9439097

Answer (score 11):

best way to do is perform bit by bit shifting

```
def reverse_Bits(n, no_of_bits):
    result = 0
    for i in range(no_of_bits):
        result <<= 1
        result |= n & 1
        n >>= 1
    return result
# for example we reverse 12 i.e 1100 which is 4 bits long
print(reverse_Bits(12,4))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def reverse_bit(num):
    result = 0
    while num:
        result = (result << 1) + (num & 1)
        num >>= 1
    return result
```

We don't really need to convert the integer into binary, since integers are actually binary in Python.

The reversing idea is like doing the in-space reversing of integers.

```
def reverse_int(x):
    result = 0
    pos_x = abs(x)
    while pos_x:
        result = result * 10 + pos_x % 10
        pos_x /= 10
    return result if x >= 0 else (-1) * result
```

For each loop, the original number is dropping the right-most bit(in binary). We get that right-most bit and multiply 2 (`<<1`) in the next loop when the new bit is added.

Comment: You have to take into account the number of bits to be reversed. For example, you want to reverse bits in a byte. You expect that 0x1 will be translated to 0x80 (0b00000001 -> 0b10000000). And with current implementation, you'll still get 0x1 on the output

Answer (score 3):

There's no need, and no way, to "convert a decimal integer to binary representation". All Python integers are represented as binary; they're just converted to decimal when you print them for convenience.

If you want to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333563/166749) to the reversal problem, you only need to find appropriate `numbits`. You can either specify this by hand, or compute the number of bits needed to represent an integer `n` with [`n.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) (new in Python 2.7 and 3.1).

However, for 65, that would give you 7, as there's no reason why 65 should require any more bits. (You might want to round up to the nearest multiple of 8...)

Comment: Not really right, as you can get a string representing the bits (`bin(n)`, or `'{:b}'.format(n)`). Plus, you can use `.bit_length()` to find the exact number of bits needed to represent a number.

Comment: @nneonneo: I was assuming the OP wants to work on the integer itself rather than a string representation, given the links. But thanks for the `bit_length` method, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the i'th bit of a number by using a shift and mask. For example, bit 6 of 65 is `(65 >> 6) & 1`. You can set a bit in a similar way by shifting 1 left the right number of times. These insights gives you code like this (which reverses x in a field of 'n' bits).

```
def reverse(x, n):
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        if (x >> i) & 1: result |= 1 << (n - 1 - i)
    return result

print bin(reverse(65, 8))
```

Answer (score 3):

An inefficient but concise method that works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3:

```
def bit_reverse(i, n):
    return int(format(i, '0%db' % n)[::-1], 2)
```

For your example:

```
>>> bit_reverse(65, 8)
130
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a Look up table (that can be generated once using methods above):

```
LUT = [0, 128, 64, 192, 32, 160, 96, 224, 16, 144, 80, 208, 48, 176, 112, 240,
       8, 136, 72, 200, 40, 168, 104, 232, 24, 152, 88, 216, 56, 184, 120,
       248, 4, 132, 68, 196, 36, 164, 100, 228, 20, 148, 84, 212, 52, 180,
       116, 244, 12, 140, 76, 204, 44, 172, 108, 236, 28, 156, 92, 220, 60,
       188, 124, 252, 2, 130, 66, 194, 34, 162, 98, 226, 18, 146, 82, 210, 50,
       178, 114, 242, 10, 138, 74, 202, 42, 170, 106, 234, 26, 154, 90, 218,
       58, 186, 122, 250, 6, 134, 70, 198, 38, 166, 102, 230, 22, 150, 86, 214,
       54, 182, 118, 246, 14, 142, 78, 206, 46, 174, 110, 238, 30, 158, 94,
       222, 62, 190, 126, 254, 1, 129, 65, 193, 33, 161, 97, 225, 17, 145, 81,
       209, 49, 177, 113, 241, 9, 137, 73, 201, 41, 169, 105, 233, 25, 153, 89,
       217, 57, 185, 121, 249, 5, 133, 69, 197, 37, 165, 101, 229, 21, 149, 85,
       213, 53, 181, 117, 245, 13, 141, 77, 205, 45, 173, 109, 237, 29, 157,
       93, 221, 61, 189, 125, 253, 3, 131, 67, 195, 35, 163, 99, 227, 19, 147,
       83, 211, 51, 179, 115, 243, 11, 139, 75, 203, 43, 171, 107, 235, 27,
       155, 91, 219, 59, 187, 123, 251, 7, 135, 71, 199, 39, 167, 103, 231, 23,
       151, 87, 215, 55, 183, 119, 247, 15, 143, 79, 207, 47, 175, 111, 239,
       31, 159, 95, 223, 63, 191, 127, 255]

def reverseBitOrder(uint8):
    return LUT[uint8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regularly there is the need to apply this operation **on array of numbers** and not for single number.
To increase speed, it's probably better to use NumPy array.
There are two solutions.

x1.34 faster than second solution:

```
import numpy as np
def reverse_bits_faster(x):
  x = np.array(x)
  bits_num = x.dtype.itemsize * 8
  # because bitwise operations may change number of bits in numbers
  one_array = np.array([1], x.dtype)
  # switch bits in-place
  for i in range(int(bits_num / 2)):
    right_bit_mask = (one_array << i)[0]
    left_bit = (x & right_bit_mask) << (bits_num - 1 - i * 2)
    left_bit_mask = (one_array << (bits_num - 1 - i))[0]
    right_bit = (x & left_bit_mask) >> (bits_num - 1 - i * 2)
    moved_bits_mask = left_bit_mask | right_bit_mask
    x = x & (~moved_bits_mask) | left_bit | right_bit
  return x
```

Slower, but more easy to understand (based on [solution proposed by Sudip Ghimire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596723/10845719)):

```
import numpy as np
def reverse_bits(x):
  x = np.array(x)
  bits_num = x.dtype.itemsize * 8
  x_reversed = np.zeros_like(x)
  for i in range(bits_num):
    x_reversed = (x_reversed << 1) | x & 1
    x >>= 1
  return x_reversed
```

Answer (score 2):

All what you need is numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.uint8(65)
print( np.packbits(np.unpackbits(x, bitorder='little')) )
```

performance:

```
py -3 -m timeit "import numpy as np; import timeit; x=np.uint8(65); timeit.timeit(lambda: np.packbits(np.unpackbits(x, bitorder='little')), number=100000)"
1 loop, best of 5: 326 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it is to loop through the bits from both end and swap each other. This i learned from EPI python book.

```
i = 0; j = 7
num = 230
print(bin(num))
while i<j:
    # Get the bits from both end iteratively
    if (x>>i)&1 != (x>>j)&1:
        # if the bits don't match swap them by creating a bit mask
        # and XOR it with the number 
        mask = (1<<i) | (1<<j)
        num ^= mask
    i += 1; j -= 1
print(bin(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and second steps have a very neat algorthom:

```
num = int(input())

while num > 0:
  reminder = num % 2
  print(f'{str(reminder)}', end = '')
  num = int(num / 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bin(x)[:1:-1]
```

one line, and it automatically goes for the top bit.  (edit: use zfill or rjust to get a fixed width - see below)

```
>>> x = 0b1011000
>>> bin(x)[:1:-1]
'0001101'
>>> x = 0b100
>>> bin(x)[:1:-1]
'001'
```

the "0b" on the front of the text-conversion is stripped by the "1" in [:1:-1] which, after the inversion (by -1) has 1 automatically added to it (sigh, range is *really* weird) before being used as the *start* point not the end.

you'll need zero-padding on the front to get it a fixed-width reversing but even there [:1:-1] will still do the auto-length-detection

zfill does the job but you need to split off the "0b" from bin()
first, *then* zfill, *then* invert (then convert to int)

```
length=10
bin(x)[2:].zfill(length)[::-1]
int(bin(x)[2:].zfill(length)[::-1],2)
```

using ljust:

```
bin(x)[:1:-1].ljust(length, '0')
```

strangely although longer i find ljust clearer.