# How to reverse the bits of each character in a string using python

Tags: python

I would like to find a way to reverse the bits of each character in a string using python.

For example, if my first character was `J`, this is ASCII `0x4a` or `0b01001010`, so would be reversed to `0x52` or `0b01010010`. If my second character was `K`, this is `0b01001011`, so would be reversed to `0xd2` or `0b11010010`, etc.

The end result should be returned as a `string`.

Speed is my number one priority here, so I am looking for a fast way to accomplish this.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681945/reversing-bits-of-python-integer

Comment: What's your current method, and what's the specific performance issue?

Comment: As you need `str` as output and want replace each character with single character, I suggest you to investigate `translate` method of `str`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added my current best method as an answer. There are no specific performance issues, I would just like it to be as fast as is reasonably possible.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you, I used this to aid in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking on board the advice, here is my solution:

```
# Pre-populate a look-up array with bit-reversed integers from 0 to 255
bytearray = []
for i in range(0, 256):
    bytearray.append(int('{:08b}'.format(i)[::-1], 2))

# Reverses the bits of each character in the input string and returns the result
# as a string
def revstr(string):
    return ''.join([chr(bytearray[ord(a)]) for a in list(string)])

print "JK".encode("hex")         # 0x4a4b
print revstr("JK").encode("hex") # 0x52d2
```

Answer (score 3):

If speed is your goal and you are working with ASCII so you only have 256 8-bit values to handle, calculate the reversed-byte values beforehand and put them in a `bytearray`, then look them up by indexing into the `bytearray`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added my own answer which implements this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 a=bin(ord("a"))
'0b'+a[::-1][0:len(a)-2]
```

If you want to do it for a lot of characters, then there are only 256 ascii characters. Store the reversed strings in a hashmap and do lookups on the hashmap. Time complexity of those lookups is O(1), but there's a fix setup time.