# How to reindex a numpy array with reversed binary representation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**How to improve the following code?**

1 )-> pass a 1-dimensional array of length `2**n`

2 )-> for every index of the array get the binary representation

3 )-> reverse the binary represenation and use it as new integer index for the corresponding value

**EXAMPLE:**

[56,209,81,42]

[00,01,10,11] (binary representation of the indices)

-> REVERSE:[00,10,01,11]

-> BECOMES:[56,81,209,42]

**Code:**

```
def order_in_reversed_bits(data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    tobinary = lambda t: np.binary_repr(t, width=len(np.binary_repr(data.shape[0]-1)))[::-1]
    func = np.vectorize(tobinary)
    a = func(np.arange(0,data.shape[0]))
    t = np.zeros(data.shape,dtype='float64')

    for i,k in enumerate(a):
        t[int(k,2)] = data[i]

    return t
```

Which built-in functionality of Numpy or Python is handy?

Comment: `vectorize` isn't going make applying `np.binary_repr` any faster.  It still generates one string per number.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you! Those hints are always helpful! And it shows my lack of understanding what happens and what I do.

Comment: The name of `np.vectorize` causes a lot of misunderstandings.  It does operate on whole arrays, but not in idealized the way that produces 10x speedups.  Others use `vectorize` to mean using multiprocessing and and fast hardware engines.  Your accepted answer gains speed simply because `'{:b}'.format` is faster than `np.binary_repr`.

Comment: I just realized `np.binary_repr` is Python code, which we can study and potentially modify.  The core action is `bin(n)`, which produces a string like '0b10001'.  It just cleans it up and adjusts for width.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know how np.fft() is implemented, but this request is part of calculating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sorted` with custom key, for example (thanks to @hpaulj for improved key function with `bin()`):

```
lst = [56,209,81,42]

def order_in_reversed_bits_python(lst):
    return [v for _, v in sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda k: bin(k[0])[:1:-1])]

print(order_in_reversed_bits_python(lst))
```

Prints:

```
[56, 81, 209, 42]
```

---

Timings:

```
import timeit
from random import randint

def order_in_reversed_bits_python(lst):
    return [v for _, v in sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda k: bin(k[0])[:1:-1])]

def order_in_reversed_bits(data):
    tobinary = lambda t: np.binary_repr(t, width=len(np.binary_repr(data.shape[0]-1)))[::-1]
    func = np.vectorize(tobinary)
    a = func(np.arange(0,data.shape[0]))
    t = np.zeros(data.shape,dtype='float64')

    for i,k in enumerate(a):
        t[int(k,2)] = data[i]

    return t

# create some large array:
lst = np.array([randint(1, 100) for _ in range(2**16)])

t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: order_in_reversed_bits_python(lst), number=1)
t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: order_in_reversed_bits(lst), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.05821935099811526
0.22723246600071434
```

which is improvement ~3.9x

Comment: I get further speedup by using `bin` in the `key`: `key=lambda k: bin(k[0])[:1:-1]`.  With the reversal, the width isn't important.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, that seems too be significant speed-up (I edited my answer)! The `bin()` was indeed my first thought, but went with the `str.format` (I couldn't figure out how to use it with `sorted` - but your version did it :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as [bit-reversal permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation). The only difficult part is to reverse the binary representation of an index. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681945/reversing-bits-of-python-integer) you will find ways to do it. I choose the simplest one:

```
def bit_reversal_permutation(n):
    indices = range(2**n)
    rev_bits = lambda x: int(format(x, f'0{n}b')[::-1], 2)
    return np.fromiter(map(rev_bits, indices), dtype=int)
```

A faster version, based on the observation that:

> Each permutation in this sequence can be generated by concatenating two sequences of numbers: the previous permutation, doubled, and the same sequence with each value increased by one.

```
def bit_reversal_permutation(n):
    indices = range(2**(n-1))
    rev_bits = lambda x: int(format(x, f'0{n-1}b')[::-1], 2)
    rev_indices = np.fromiter(map(rev_bits, indices), dtype=int)
    return np.concatenate([2*rev_indices, 2*rev_indices + 1])
```

Example:

```
n = 4
a = np.random.randn(2**n)
inds_rev = bit_reversal_permutation(n)

a[inds_rev]
```

Comment: I don't know if I compared the code in the right way, but it runs slower and I also run into a prolem for high n:  'values: lst = np.array([randint(1, 100) for _ in range(2 ** 8)])' I receive: rev_indices = np.fromiter(map(rev_bits, indices), dtype=int)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long, probably because of dtype.

Comment: @user2853437 how did you test it? For n = 8 there shouldn't be any problems. For `lst = np.array([randint(1, 100) for _ in range(2 ** 8)])` you should use `n = 8`, `inds_rev = bit_reversal_permutation(n)` and `lst[inds_rev]`.

Comment: Of course for n > 64 you will have problem with numpy.