# Converting integer to binary for SPI transfer

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I am trying to convert an integer to 3 bytes to send via the SPI protocol to control a [MAX6921](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6921-MAX6931.pdf) serial chip. I am using `spi.xfer2()` but cannot get it to work as expected.

In my code, I can call `spi.xfer2([0b00000000, 0b11101100, 0b10000000])` it displays the letter "H" on my display, but when I try and convert the int value for this `79616`, it doesn't give the correct output:

```py
val = 79616
spi.xfer2(val.to_bytes(3, 'little'))
```

My full code so far is on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexholsgrove/nixie-clock/blob/raspberry-pi-example/examples/raspberrypi/iv18.py), and for comparison, this is my working [code for Arduino](https://github.com/alexholsgrove/nixie-clock/blob/raspberry-pi-example/examples/arduino/iv18-uno/iv18-uno.ino).

### More details

I have an [IV-18 VFD](https://github.com/blinken/nixie-clock/blob/main/datasheets/iv-18/IV-18.pdf) tube [driver module](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Antique-display-vacuum-integrated-Arduino/dp/B08TX6CSZ5), which came with some [example code](https://github.com/blinken/nixie-clock/blob/main/examples/esp32/src/esp32_demo.c) for an ESP32 board. The driver module has a 20 output [MAX6921](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6921-MAX6931.pdf) serial chip to drive the vacuum tube.

To sent "H" to the second grid position (as the first grid only displays a dot or a dash) the bits are sent to MAX6921 in order OUT19 --> OUT0, so using the LSB in my table below. The letter "H" has an int value `79616`

I can successfully send this, manually, via SPI using:

```py
spi.xfer2([0b00000000, 0b11101100, 0b10000000])
```

The problem I have is trying to convert other letters in a string to the correct bits. I can retrieve the integer value for any character (0-9, A-Z) in a string, but can't then work out how to convert it to the right format for `spi.xfer()` / `spi.xfer2()`

**My Code**

```py
def display_write(val):
    spi.xfer2(val.to_bytes(3, 'little'))

# Loops over the grid positions
def update_display():
    global grid_index

    val = grids[grid_index] | char_to_code(message[grid_index:grid_index+1])

    display_write(val)

    grid_index += 1
    if (grid_index >= 9):
        grid_index = 0
```

The full source for my code so far is on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexholsgrove/nixie-clock/blob/raspberry-pi-example/examples/raspberrypi/iv18.py)

Map for MAX6921 Data out pins to the IV-18 tube pins:

| BIT | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IV-18 | G9 | G8 | G7 | G6 | G5 | G4 | G3 | G2 | G1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | DP |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| MAX6921 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |  |  |  |  |

[IV-18 Pinout diagram](https://nixieclocks.shop/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Energy-Pillar-IV-18-08.jpg)

Comment: This is a general programming question, not a Pi specific question.

Comment: @joan apologies - I didn't know if there was anything RPi specific in the way I use spidev. Can you flag to migrate this to SO please, or am I better to close this and open a new question there instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing bits of Python integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681945/reversing-bits-of-python-integer)

Comment: `for i in map(lambda y: int('{:08b}'.format(y)[::-1], 2), int(79616).to_bytes(3, 'little')): print("%02x" % i)` --> `00 ec 80` which is what you want.