# How do you think masking bit problems?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift, bitmask

For example in this answer to a reversing bits function problem made 4 years ago:

[reverse_Bits function]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596723/19574301

Code:

```
def reverse_Bits(n, no_of_bits):
      result = 0
      for i in range(no_of_bits):
         result <<= 1
         result |= n & 1
         n >>= 1
      return result
```

I don't understand how to think the problem at all.

You multiply actual number (n) by one in order to check the first right side bit. Then you **right shift** this number by one so you are checking if the second bit is 0 when you **and** it again, and this for all bits. So basically you're **adding** 1 to the result if there is a 1 in the actual (?) bit. Aside you **left shift** the result so I understand you're trying to put the bit in its correct index and if there is a one you **add** it... I get lost here.

I mean, I know the code works and I know how but I couldn't do it from zero without having this reference because I don't know how you achieve thinking every step of the algorithm.

I don't know if I explain my problem or if it's just a mess but hoping somebody can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, "how would I write this from scratch, without any help?" then I find personally that it comes about from a combination of sketching out simple cases, working through them manually, and progressive implementation.

For example, you may have started with example: You have the number 3 (because it is easy) and you want to reverse bits:

```
3 = 0000 0011 b 

need to &1 and if it is non-zero, write 1000 0000 b
need to &2 and if it is non-zero, write 0100 0000 b
need to &4 and as it is zero, write nothing... 
...
```

Okay, how can I automate 1,2,4,8,16,32 .. ? Can have a variable which will double, or I can left-shift a number by 1. Take your pick, does not matter.

For writing the values, same thing, how can I write 1000 0000 b and then 0100 0000 b, etc? Well start off as 1000 0000 b and divide by 2 or right-shift by 1.

With these two simple things, you will end up with something like this for one bit:

```
result = 0
src_mask = 0x01
dst_mask = 0x80 
if number & src_mask != 0:
    result |= dst_mask
```

One bit working. Then you add a loop so that you can do all bits and add a *2 for the src_mask and a /2 for the dst_mask as you do it to address each bit. Again this is all figured out from the scribbles on paper listing what I want to happen for each bit.

Then comes optimization, I don't like the 'if' so can I figure out a way of directly adding the bit without testing? if it was 0 it will add 0 and if the bit is set, then I add the bit?

This is generally the progression. Manual scribbles, first design and then step-by-step enhancements.