# fft algorithm yields imprecise results

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, fft, dft, cmath

I'm trying to implement the fft (fast fourier transform) based on dft(discrete fourier transform) matrix factorization.In the following code, both fft and the straightforward method(i.e.: multiply the dft matrix directly with v) are implemented in order to test the validity of my implementation of fft.

```
import numpy as n
import cmath, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=n.array([1,-1,2,-3])
w=v
N=len(v)
t=[0]*N
M=n.zeros((N,N),dtype=complex)
z=n.exp(2j*math.pi/N)
for a in range(N):
    for b in range(N):
        M[a][b]=n.exp(2j*math.pi*a*b/N)
print (n.dot(v,M))
plt.plot(n.dot(v,M))
def f(x):
    x=n.concatenate([x[::2],x[1::2]])
    return x

while (w!=f(v)).any():
    v=f(v)
print(v)
a=2
while a<=N:

    for k in range(N/a):
        for y in range(a/2):
            t[y]=v[a*k+y]
        for i in range(a/2):
            v[a*k+i]+=v[a*k+i+a/2]*(z**i)
            v[a*k+i+a/2]=t[i]-v[a*k+i+a/2]*(z**i)
    a*=2    
print(v)
plt.plot(v)

plt.show()
```

I've tried this with lots of values of v, sometimes the outputs of these two methods yield exactly the same result but other times they are close to each other but not exactly the same. They haven't gone far away from each other yet after a few tests each with a different value of v.

Is there anything that I'm missing that causes the imprecision of the code?

**EDIT**:
Please note that the code is designed for Python 2 (because of the implicit integer divisions).

Comment: are you running on python 2?

Comment: Don't disregard the warnings. *ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  `v[a*k+i+a/2]=t[i]-v[a*k+i+a/2]*(z**i)`* ring a bell? (Hint: you set the correct `dtype` for `M`. Try for `v` too.)

Comment: It seems that the solution is actually in the declaration of `v` (thanks @kazemakase). Try `v=n.array([1,-1,2,-3], dtype=complex)` instead. At least for me the curves than appear on top of each other.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Hi Thomas, please see my comment under your answer .

Comment: @kazemakase That works for what I show in the post, but it doesn't for v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] And the warning still shows up after I set up dtype for v.

Comment: @ThomasKühn That's correct. running on python 2.7.13

Comment: @pxc3110 Read the warning carefully. It probably happens in the call to `plot`, which does not support complex values (So it simply drops the imaginary part).

Comment: @kazemakase That's quite correct, but even plotting `abs` or `np.real` of the results produces the discrepancy -- looks like the declaration thing was just one problem after all ..

Comment: @ThomasKühn Indeed, I think the main problem is that I did wrong on that permutation part.

Comment: under for i in range(a/2), z should depend on a, in particular, z=exp(2jpi/a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is not in the algorithm, but in the declaration of v (thanks @kazemakase). Try

```
v=n.array([1,-1,2,-3], dtype=complex)
```

instead. At least for me the curves then appear on top of each other:

[image]

**EDIT**

This was quite the journey. I wasn't able to figure out what's wrong with your code, but it looks like there are several errors, both with the dft and the fft. In the end I wrote my own version of the fft based on [this document] (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/2001/pub/www/notes/fourier/fourier.pdf) (pages 6 -- 9 hold all the information you need). Maybe you can go through the algorithm and figure out where your problems lie. The algorithm for the bit reversal can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333563/2454357) (or alternatively in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682003/2454357) ). I tested the code for linear vectors of different lengths -- let me know if you find any mistakes.

```
import numpy as np
import cmath

def bit_reverse(x,n):
    """
    Reverse the last n bits of x
    """

    ##from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682003/2454357
    ##formstr = '{{:0{}b}}'.format(n)
    ##return int(formstr.format(x)[::-1],2)

    ##from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333563/2454357
    return sum(1<<(n-1-i) for i in range(n) if x>>i&1)

def permute_vector(v):
    """
    Permute vector v such that the indices of the result
    correspond to the bit-reversed indices of the original.
    Returns the permuted input vector and the number of bits used.
    """
    ##check that len(v) == 2**n
    ##and at the same time find permutation length:
    L = len(v)
    comp = 1
    bits = 0
    while comp<L:
        comp *= 2
        bits += 1
    if comp != L:
        raise ValueError('permute_vector: wrong length of v -- must be 2**n')
    rindices = [bit_reverse(i,bits)for i in range(L)]
    return v[rindices],bits

def dft(v):
    N = v.shape[0]
    a,b = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(0,N-1,N,dtype=np.complex128),
        np.linspace(0,N-1,N,dtype=np.complex128),
    )
    M = np.exp((-2j*np.pi*a*b)/N)

    return np.dot(M,v)


def fft(v):
    w,bits = permute_vector(v)
    N = w.shape[0]
    z=np.exp(np.array(-2j,dtype=np.complex128)*np.pi/N)

    ##starting fft
    for i in range(bits): 
        dist = 2**i  ##distance between 'exchange pairs'
        group = dist*2 ##size of sub-groups
        for start in range(0,N,group):
            for offset in range(group//2):
                pos1 = start+offset
                pos2 = pos1+dist
                alpha1 = z**((pos1*N//group)%N)
                alpha2 = z**((pos2*N//group)%N)
                w[pos1],w[pos2] = w[pos1]+alpha1*w[pos2],w[pos1]+alpha2*w[pos2]
    return w

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #test the fft
    for n in [2**i for i in range(1,5)]:
        print('-'*25+'n={}'.format(n)+'-'*25)
        v = np.linspace(0,n-1,n, dtype=np.complex128)
        print('v = ')
        print(v)
        print('fft(v) = ')
        print(fft(v))
        print('dft(v) = ')
        print(dft(v))
        print('relative error:')
        print(abs(fft(v)-dft(v))/abs(dft(v)))
```

This gives the following output:

```
-------------------------n=2-------------------------
v = 
[ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j]
fft(v) = 
[ 1. +0.00000000e+00j -1. -1.22464680e-16j]
dft(v) = 
[ 1. +0.00000000e+00j -1. -1.22464680e-16j]
relative error:
[ 0.  0.]
-------------------------n=4-------------------------
v = 
[ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j  2.+0.j  3.+0.j]
fft(v) = 
[ 6. +0.00000000e+00j -2. +2.00000000e+00j -2. -4.89858720e-16j
 -2. -2.00000000e+00j]
dft(v) = 
[ 6. +0.00000000e+00j -2. +2.00000000e+00j -2. -7.34788079e-16j
 -2. -2.00000000e+00j]
relative error:
[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   3.51083347e-16]
-------------------------n=8-------------------------
v = 
[ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j  2.+0.j  3.+0.j  4.+0.j  5.+0.j  6.+0.j  7.+0.j]
fft(v) = 
[ 28. +0.00000000e+00j  -4. +9.65685425e+00j  -4. +4.00000000e+00j
  -4. +1.65685425e+00j  -4. -7.10542736e-15j  -4. -1.65685425e+00j
  -4. -4.00000000e+00j  -4. -9.65685425e+00j]
dft(v) = 
[ 28. +0.00000000e+00j  -4. +9.65685425e+00j  -4. +4.00000000e+00j
  -4. +1.65685425e+00j  -4. -3.42901104e-15j  -4. -1.65685425e+00j
  -4. -4.00000000e+00j  -4. -9.65685425e+00j]
relative error:
[  0.00000000e+00   6.79782332e-16   7.40611132e-16   1.85764404e-15
   9.19104080e-16   3.48892999e-15   3.92837008e-15   1.35490975e-15]
-------------------------n=16-------------------------
v = 
[  0.+0.j   1.+0.j   2.+0.j   3.+0.j   4.+0.j   5.+0.j   6.+0.j   7.+0.j
   8.+0.j   9.+0.j  10.+0.j  11.+0.j  12.+0.j  13.+0.j  14.+0.j  15.+0.j]
fft(v) = 
[ 120. +0.00000000e+00j   -8. +4.02187159e+01j   -8. +1.93137085e+01j
   -8. +1.19728461e+01j   -8. +8.00000000e+00j   -8. +5.34542910e+00j
   -8. +3.31370850e+00j   -8. +1.59129894e+00j   -8. +2.84217094e-14j
   -8. -1.59129894e+00j   -8. -3.31370850e+00j   -8. -5.34542910e+00j
   -8. -8.00000000e+00j   -8. -1.19728461e+01j   -8. -1.93137085e+01j
   -8. -4.02187159e+01j]
dft(v) = 
[ 120. +0.00000000e+00j   -8. +4.02187159e+01j   -8. +1.93137085e+01j
   -8. +1.19728461e+01j   -8. +8.00000000e+00j   -8. +5.34542910e+00j
   -8. +3.31370850e+00j   -8. +1.59129894e+00j   -8. -6.08810394e-14j
   -8. -1.59129894e+00j   -8. -3.31370850e+00j   -8. -5.34542910e+00j
   -8. -8.00000000e+00j   -8. -1.19728461e+01j   -8. -1.93137085e+01j
   -8. -4.02187159e+01j]
relative error:
[  0.00000000e+00   1.09588741e-15   1.45449990e-15   6.36716793e-15
   8.53211992e-15   9.06818284e-15   1.30922044e-14   5.40949529e-15
   1.11628436e-14   1.23698141e-14   1.50430426e-14   3.02428869e-14
   2.84810617e-14   1.16373983e-14   1.10680934e-14   3.92841628e-15]
```

This was quite a nice challenge -- I learned a lot! You can verify the results of the code online, for instance [here](http://calculator.vhex.net/calculator/fast-fourier-transform-calculator-fft/1d-discrete-fourier-transform).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did as you told so, it worked for the one you show, but it didn't quite work for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: @pxc3110 do you have a link to the algorithm you try to implement?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/complex-matrices-fast-fourier-transform-fft/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.2sum.pdf

Comment: The basic idea is that the discrete fourier matrix exp(2j*pi*a*b/N) can be factorized into identity matrices, diagonal matrices and the oddity permutation matrices.

Comment: Side note: it's interesting to observe that two methods coincide exactly for any complex 4d vector v, at least seems to be for all the tests so far.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I like the fact that you learned something, which is the main point of this site. The following link provides practical implementations instead of the theoretical part: https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientificRecipes I think you may want to check this out as well?