# MSB to LSB and vice versa

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Algorithm for Bit Reversal ( from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c)

How do I mirror the bits of a 32-bit integer (as in MSB to LSB; and vice-versa) in C++?

Ex: `1101_0010_....0 to 0...._0100_1011`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c