# is there any standard C functions for bitswapping?

Tags: c, linux, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Algorithm for Bit Reversal ( from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c)

I have a 64-bit word and I want to do the following operations on it.

First I want to do a bit-swap (swap Bit 63 with Bit 0 
                               swap Bit 62 with Bit 1  and so on)

Once the above operation is completed I want to do a byte-swap Swap between Byte 0 and Byte 7
                                                                            Byte 1 and Byte 6 and so on.

Now we do have an inbuilt function in gcc linux to do the second part bswap_64().Is there any function do do the first part available in gcc linux C

Comment: No. But we do have these things called "operators" which do those operations...

Comment: **Why** do you want to swap bits? either FFT or homework, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser.it is neither FFT not homework.I have captured some idle 10GE frames which I am trying to convert to XGMII coded frames. :)

Comment: "Dupe" is a good answer, but it's not actually a duplicate of his question.

Comment: @therefromhere: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c/746203#746203) addresses perfectly the question.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I disagree.  It's highly relevant, but it's not actually answering the question that was asked - "Is there a standard C function for bitswapping" (of course the answer should be No, with a link to that answer).

Comment: Pity for the dup/closing. I had to append my solution to the older topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The net effect is the same as bit-swapping each byte in place.  For example, byte 0 is first copied to byte 7 with its bits reversed, then copied back to byte0 with no bit-reversal.

There's no built-in support for any of these operations, but bit-swapping each byte in place should be fairly straightforward.  The most efficient method is probably a 256-element lookup table.

```
uint64_t the_word = /* whatever */
unsigned char *bytes = &the_word;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
     bytes[i] = reverse[bytes[i]];
}
```

where:

```
const unsigned char reverse[UCHAR_MAX+1] {
    0x00, 0x80, ..., 0xFF
}
```

You can write a small program that computes the bit-swapped value for each byte value and generates the source code for the initialization of `bytes`.  (Or, since you're writing the code to do the computation anyway, you can just use it in your program in place of the lookup table; it depends on how important speed is.)

This assumes, for example, that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is not guaranteed by the language.

I have not tested this.

Comment: According to benchmarks [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c), it might be better to manually unroll the loop and use integer arithmetic, since compilers may not be *that* clever (and byte addressing is usually slow). Declaring `bytes` as `restrict` could also help. Benchmarking is of course your guide here.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I just fixed the typo.