# What does this actually do? - Crazy C++ function

Tags: c++, networking

I'm working with some legacy code and I came across a function which is apparently used to perform network byte order conversions on an arbitrarily long field (bigger than ntohl can handle).

I can't understand it well enough to tell if it's doing anything more than reversing the byte order over the msg buffer range though (or even if it will do that reliably).  Can someone help me break this down and analyze it so I can replace it with something that's more intelligible (or at least comment it well)!?

```
void swapit(unsigned char *msg, int length) {
  for(;length>0;length--, msg++) {
    *msg = ((*msg * 0x0802LU & 0x22110LU) |
            (*msg * 0x8020LU & 0x88440LU)) *
           0x10101LU >> 16;
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/746203/367273 where this function appears along with numerous alternatives. Voting to close on that basis.

Comment: Erm... should I take that as a "it's perfectly safe and don't worry about it?"

Comment: That's up to you. It clearly deserves a comment (and perhaps a link to that other SO question? :-))

Comment: Oh I found it in there now :)  Thanks man.  I feel a lot better knowing whoever wrote this probably looked it up, haha.

Comment: Hehe, make you sure comment it with a link for the next maintainer :)

Comment: Definitely.  This was making my head split :p

Comment: Voted to reopen... would be very interested to see this broken down and explained as requested.

Comment: I'd actually appreciate that.  Since it is a very fast way to achieve this in a 32-bit system, I'd like to keep it in the code - but I'd feel better leaving a comment or explaining the magic numbers/ >>16 and all that (which I'm having trouble doing admittedly :( )

Comment: Beware that reversing *bit* order (which this does) isn't the same as reversing *byte* order. Sending data from a big-endian to a little-endian system doesn't require bit reversal.

Comment: Someone certainly hated a person who was supposed to read the code after it's been written.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To see how it works, consider applying the operations to the bit pattern `abcdefgh`.
I'll represent binary numbers with `.` for `0`, so the non-zero bits stand out.

The first subexpression is:

```
  ........ ........ abcdefgh
* ........ ....1... ......1. (0x0802)
= .....abc defgh..a bcdefgh.
& ......1. ..1....1 ...1.... (0x22110)
= ......b. ..f....a ...e....
```

The second is:

```
  ........ ........ abcdefgh
* ........ 1....... ..1..... (0x8020)
= .abcdefg h..abcde fgh.....
& ....1... 1....1.. .1...... (0x88440)
= ....d... h....c.. .g......
```

Combining them and multiplying by the final constant gives:

```
  ......b. ..f....a ...e....
| ....d... h....c.. .g......
= ....d.b. h.f..c.a .g.e....
* .......1 .......1 .......1 (0x10101)
= ....d.b. h.f..c.a .g.e....
 +h.f..c.a .g.e.... ........
 +.g.e.... ........ ........
= hgfedcba hgfe.c.a .g.e....
```

Finally shifting down by 16 bits gives `hgfedcba`, the reverse of the original pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it made it a lot easier to understand :)

Answer (score 6):

From this question: [Best Algorithm for Bit Reversal ( from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c)

It appears to be reversing bits.

```
0010 0000 => 0000 0100
```

Answer (score 3):

It's mentioned in bit twiddling hacks as [Reverse the bits in a byte with 7 operations (no 64-bit)](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith32Bits).

Comment: +1 for the reference to bit twiddling hacks! definitely worth knowing when you work with low-level code.