# C reverse binary

Tags: c, binary, binary-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C reverse bits in unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144800/c-reverse-bits-in-unsigned-integer)

How can I reverse a binary number only using binary operators?

E.g:

```
11100000 -> 00000111
00110100 -> 00101100
00111111 -> 11111100
```

Comment: call it reverse instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9144870/745924

Comment: Done `s/invert/reverse/`, with "invert" is way too easy to think you just want a `not`.

Comment: I can not just call it reverse, they are pulled from a buffer and I need to reverse them. I believe that @Banthar's comment has what I need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this sort of thing I recommend that you take a look at the awesome page [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith64BitsDiv).

Here is just one example solution taken from that page:

> **Reverse the bits in a byte with 3 operations (64-bit multiply and
>   modulus division)**
>
> ```
> unsigned char b; // reverse this (8-bit) byte 
> b = (b * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;
> ```

And as pointed out in the comments, here's another option:

> **Reverse an N-bit quantity in parallel in 5 * lg(N) operations**
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // 32-bit word to reverse bit order
>
> // swap odd and even bits
> v = ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((v & 0x55555555) << 1);
> // swap consecutive pairs
> v = ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((v & 0x33333333) << 2);
> // swap nibbles ... 
> v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
> // swap bytes
> v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
> // swap 2-byte long pairs
> v = ( v >> 16             ) | ( v               << 16);
> ```

Comment: I was going to post this but you beat me to it.

Comment: And what about a 32 bits variable?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong Please refer to the Section `Reverse an N-bit quantity in parallel in 5 * lg(N) operations` in Bit Twiddling Hacks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html?1=1#BitReverseObvious). There's an entire section on reversing bit sequences.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this website http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Reversing bit sequences
Reverse bits the obvious way
Reverse bits in word by lookup table
Reverse the bits in a byte with 3 operations (64-bit multiply and modulus division)
Reverse the bits in a byte with 4 operations (64-bit multiply, no division)
Reverse the bits in a byte with 7 operations (no 64-bit, only 32)
Reverse an N-bit quantity in parallel with 5 * lg(N) operations