# opposite of binary number

Tags: php, binary

I have a binary number 11000 i need to flip the number to get the answer 00111
and i need the result in PHP, i did it using the for loop but how can i do it using bitwise operator i think we can do it using ^ operator here is the PHP solution:

```
function getIntegerComplement($n) {
    // $n is a decimal number
    $binary = decbin($n);
    $arr = str_split($binary);  

    $complement = "";
    foreach($arr as $i)
      $complement .= ($i == 0) ? (1) : (0);
}
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: This could help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144800/c-reverse-bits-in-unsigned-integer

Comment: Do you need to reverse or just flip the bits ?

Comment: flip the bits sorry... like all 0 converted to 1 and 1 to 0...

Answer (score 3):

If you negate the whole int, you'll get a negative number: as int consists of 32 bits (usually), and all of them will be negated. And when the 1-st bit becomes 1, php will treat it as a negative number. And you want to negate only last 5 bits. Here it is done, using the $val + $mask (mod 2):

```
<?php
$val = bindec('11000');
$mask = bindec('11111');
$val = $val ^ $mask;

print sprintf('%05d', decbin($val));
```

Prints 00111, just as expected.

Comment: i want the binary in result

Comment: this ans is not correct... u used the binary 11000 so the result should be 00111... replace all 1s to 0 and 0 to 1

Comment: @WasifKhalil This is absolutely correct. The leading zeroes are not output. So, 00111 = 111. Use printf, if you want to output the zeroes.

Comment: = Take a decimal number
 = convert it to binary
 = convert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0
 = convert that binary to decimal
 = echo that decimal

Answer (score 2):

Use the [bitwise NOT operator:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
return ~$n;
```

Comment: can u explain a bit more? i have a binary 110010 i want the result 001101

Answer (score 0):

Use "NOT" ( ~ ). 
It reverses the supplied value:

```
function getIntegerComplement($n) {
return ~$n;
}
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

> **~ $a**  ---> Not: *Bits that are set in $a are not set, and vice versa.*

Comment: not getting the exact result for binary numbers $n is a decimal num

Comment: you put in a 0, result is 1. i do not quite understand what else you wnat to achieve... just run decbin($n) on your decimal number and you get the binary result which you may now reverse using the NOT operator

Comment: i want to achieve this:
= Take a decimal number
 = convert it to binary
 = convert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0
 = convert that binary to decimal
 = echo that decimal

Comment: function getIntegerComplement2($n) {
 echo "this is the num: ".$n;
 
 echo "<br>";
 $binary = decbin($n);
 echo "this is binary: " . $binary;
 
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Flipped the binary numbers? ". ~$binary;
}

Comment: above code has this result: this is the num: 50
this is binary: 110010
Flipped the binary numbers? ÎÎÏÏÎÏ