# Conversion to little endian format in C

Tags: c, endianness

I have an array  `int16_t arr[4];` . What I want to do is to convert a value in this array to little endian. For example, let us say I have 0x1d02 on the first index, but I need 0x21d there. Is there any elegant way of converting that and writing it back to the array or how are these things done? Note that I just expressed myself in hex, because its easier to see the problem.

Comment: I dont know, your 1234 is big endian, now i need that in little endian, so 3412.

Comment: This answer goes over how to reverse a binary number in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144800/c-reverse-bits-in-unsigned-integer

Comment: Your using a signed type instead of unsigned complicates things, but that question addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define BS16(x) (((x) >> 8) | ((x) << 8))
```

```
int main(void)
{
    uint16_t arr[] = {0x1122, 0x2233, 0xaabb};
    printf("%hx %hx %hx\n", BS16(arr[0]), BS16(arr[1]), BS16(arr[2]));
    arr[0] = BS16(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ty, this seems to be what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <byteswap.h>

arr[0] = bswap_16(arr[0]);
```

[reference](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/bswap.3.en.html)

Comment: Should have mentioned i work on a embedded system, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not portable. Not available on most embedded systems.  Not always "magic" libraries or macros are needed.,