# Fastest 64-bit population count (Hamming weight)

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, simd, avx

I had to calculate the Hamming weight for a quite fast continious flow of 64-bit data and using the `popcnt` assembly instruction throws me a exception om my Intel Core i7-4650U.

I checked my bible Hacker's delight and scanned the web for all kinds of algorithms (it's a bunch out there since they started tackling this 'problem' at the birth of computing).

I spent the weekend playing around with some ideas of my own and came up with these algorithms, where I'm almost at the speed I can move data in and out of the CPU.

```
    //64-bit popcnt using BMI2
_popcnt_bmi2:
        mov         (%rdi),%r11
        pext        %r11,%r11,%r11
        not         %r11
        tzcnt       %r11,%r11
        mov         %r11,(%rdx)
        add         $8h,%rdi
        add         $8h,%rdx
        dec         %rsi
        jnz         _popcnt_bmi2
        ret
```

In the above code I use `pext` (BMI2) where the incoming data is using itself as the mask. Then all bits existing will collapse starting with the least significant bit in the result register (itself again). Then I need to calculate the number of collapsed bits so I invert all bits then use `tzcnt` to count the number of, now zeroes. I thought it was a quite nice idea.

Then I also tried a AVX2 approach:

```
//64-bit popcnt using AVX2
_popcnt_avx2:
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm2
        add         $20h,%rcx
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm3
        add         $20h,%rcx
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm4
popcnt_avx2_loop:
        vmovdqa     (%rdi),%ymm0
        vpand       %ymm0, %ymm2, %ymm1
        vpandn      %ymm0, %ymm2, %ymm0
        vpsrld      $4h,%ymm0, %ymm0
        vpshufb     %ymm1, %ymm3, %ymm1
        vpshufb     %ymm0, %ymm3, %ymm0
        vpaddb      %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0       //popcnt (8-bits)
        vpsadbw     %ymm0,%ymm4,%ymm0       //popcnt (64-bits)
        vmovdqa     %ymm0,(%rdx)
        add         $20h,%rdi
        add         $20h,%rdx
        dec         %rsi
        jnz         popcnt_avx2_loop
```

In the AVX2 case I read 32 bytes, then mask out the nibbles (`ymm2`), then I use `ymm3` as a look up table for bit counting the nibbles. Then I add the results to 8-bit's, and then I use the super condensed `vpsadbw` to add 8 bytes to a 64-bit value (`ymm4` = 0).

Anyone got something faster up their sleves?

**Edit:**

The failing `POPCNT` was due to to a error I made in my code, that function works om my Intel Core i7-4650U. Please see my post below displaying the bench results.

Comment: I think the real question is: Why does `popcnt` crash? Your processor has it. Is it disabled via some VM or BIOS config?

Comment: Does it crash if you use builtins instead of handrolled assembly? For instance GCC offers `__builtin_popcountll`.

Comment: @peppe that just compiles to a `popcnt` anyway, so what's the difference?

Comment: @harold: that maybe there's a mistake in OP's assembly. Alignment or whatever.

Comment: The built in `__builtin_popcountll` produced some super slow code. It produced the correct result but was 3 times slower than my hand- made code. (have not looked at the produced code only the benchmark result. will do that tomorrow.).

Regarding alignment it's the same for all other assembly routines (.align 2) and the data masses are aligned to 32 bytes boundaries else `vmovdqa` would crash.

Comment: Did you try to compile with `-mpopcnt`? With this option `__builtin_popcountll` should compile exactly to `popcntq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK came to the conclusion that it was no idea of trying to be 'smart', I benched:

the built in intrinsic popcount: `_mm_popcnt_u64`

bmi2:`__tzcnt_u64(~_pext_u64(data[i],data[i]));`
against three assembler functions

popcnt, bmi2 and avx2.

They all run at the speed you can move memory in and out of my:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

-Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v3 @ 3.50GHz

FYI:

main.c:

```
// Hamming weight bench

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DISPLAY_HEIGHT  4
#define DISPLAY_WIDTH   32
#define NUM_DATA_OBJECTS  40000000
#define ITTERATIONS 20

// The source data (+32 to avoid the quantization out of memory problem)
__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) static long long unsigned data[NUM_DATA_OBJECTS+32]={};
__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) static long long unsigned data_out[NUM_DATA_OBJECTS+32]={};
__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) static unsigned char k1[32*3]={
    0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,0x0f,
    0x00,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x02,0x03,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x02,0x03,0x03,0x04,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
};


extern "C" {
void popcnt_popcnt(long long unsigned[],unsigned int,long long unsigned[]);
void popcnt_bmi2(long long unsigned[],unsigned int,long long unsigned[]);
void popcnt_avx2(long long unsigned[],unsigned int,long long unsigned[],unsigned char[]);
}

void populate_data()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA_OBJECTS; i++)
    {
        data[i] = rand();
    }
}

void display_source_data()
{
    printf ("\r\nData in(start):\r\n");
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < DISPLAY_HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DISPLAY_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            printf ("0x%02llux,",data[i+(j*DISPLAY_WIDTH)]);
        }
        printf ("\r\n");
    }
}

void bench_popcnt()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA_OBJECTS; i++)
    {
        data_out[i] = _mm_popcnt_u64(data[i]);
    }
}

void bench_move_data_memcpy()
{
    memcpy(data_out,data,NUM_DATA_OBJECTS*8);
}

// __tzcnt64 ??
void bench_bmi2()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA_OBJECTS; i++)
    {
        data_out[i]=__tzcnt_u64(~_pext_u64(data[i],data[i]));
    }
}

void display_dest_data()
{
    printf ("\r\nData out:\r\n");
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < DISPLAY_HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DISPLAY_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            printf ("0x%02llux,",data_out[i+(j*DISPLAY_WIDTH)]);
        }
        printf ("\r\n");
    }
}


int main() {
    struct timeval t0;
    struct timeval t1;
    long elapsed[ITTERATIONS]={0};
    long avrg=0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        bench_move_data_memcpy();
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i]= (((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000);
        printf ("Time_to_move_data_without_processing: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average time_to_move_data: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        bench_popcnt();
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i] = ((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000;
        printf ("popcnt: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average popcnt: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        bench_bmi2();
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i] = ((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000;
        printf ("bmi2: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average bmi2: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();


    printf ("Now test the assembler functions\n");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        popcnt_popcnt(data,NUM_DATA_OBJECTS,data_out);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i] = ((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000;
        printf ("popcnt_asm: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average popcnt_asm: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        popcnt_bmi2(data,NUM_DATA_OBJECTS,data_out);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i] = ((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000;
        printf ("bmi2_asm: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average bmi2_asm: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITTERATIONS; i++)
    {
        populate_data();
        //    display_source_data();
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        popcnt_avx2(data,(unsigned int)ceil((NUM_DATA_OBJECTS*8)/32.0),data_out,k1);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed[i] = ((t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec)/1000;
        printf ("avx2_asm: %ld\n",elapsed[i]);
    }

    avrg=0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < ITTERATIONS; i++){
        avrg+=elapsed[i];
    }
    printf ("Average avx2_asm: %ld\n",avrg/(ITTERATIONS-1));

    //display_dest_data();

    return 0;
}
```

The engine.s

```
//
//  avx2_bmi2_popcnt bench
//

.global popcnt_bmi2 , popcnt_avx2, popcnt_popcnt
.align 2

//64-bit popcnt using the built-in popcnt instruction
popcnt_popcnt:
        popcntq     (%rdi), %r11
        mov         %r11,(%rdx)
        add         $8,%rdi
        add         $8,%rdx
        dec         %rsi
        jnz         popcnt_popcnt
        ret

//64-bit popcnt using BMI2
popcnt_bmi2:
        mov         (%rdi),%r11
        pextq       %r11,%r11,%r11
        not         %r11
        tzcnt       %r11,%r11
        mov         %r11,(%rdx)
        add         $8,%rdi
        add         $8,%rdx
        dec         %rsi
        jnz         popcnt_bmi2
        ret

//64-bit popcnt using AVX2
popcnt_avx2:
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm2
        add         $0x20,%rcx
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm3
        add         $0x20,%rcx
        vmovdqa     (%rcx),%ymm4
popcnt_avx2_loop:
        vmovdqa     (%rdi),%ymm0
        vpand       %ymm0, %ymm2, %ymm1
        vpandn      %ymm0, %ymm2, %ymm0
        vpsrld      $4,%ymm0, %ymm0
        vpshufb     %ymm1, %ymm3, %ymm1
        vpshufb     %ymm0, %ymm3, %ymm0
        vpaddb      %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0
        vpsadbw     %ymm0,%ymm4,%ymm0
        vmovdqa     %ymm0,(%rdx)
        add         $0x20,%rdi
        add         $0x20,%rdx
        dec         %rsi
        jnz         popcnt_avx2_loop
        ret
```

Compile the sources:

`g++ -march=native -mavx -mpopcnt -O3 main.c engine.s`

set the CPU to performance:

`cpufreq-set -g performance`

Run the bench:

`sudo chrt -r 10 ./a.out`

Result:

**Average time_to_move_data: 61**

**Average popcnt: 61**

**Average bmi2: 61**

*Now test the assembler functions*

**Average popcnt_asm: 61**

**Average bmi2_asm: 61**

**Average avx2_asm: 61**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a table-based approach, like:

```
unsigned char bitcnt[256] = {0,1,1,2,1, ... ,7,8};

unsigned char* p = &the64bitWord;

nbits = bitcnt[p[0]]
  + bitcnt[p[1]]
  + bitcnt[p[2]]
  ...
  + bitcnt[p[7]];
```

or maybe roll it yourself in asm.

Comment: yes. It's something I thought about, and it's described in: [Haming Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). 
Where they produce a 65k table and: `return (wordbits[i&0xFFFF] + wordbits[i>>16]);` That's for 32-bits, for 64-bits that would be 4 accesses to L2 cache. So it's definitely a candidate. I'll test that  for sure.

Comment: That's significantly slower than the code OP showed

Comment: The lookup approach is slower than what I already have, since it would require: one `and` three `pext`, four `mov` and three `add` if I use a 65k table for a 64-bit result.

Comment: @AndersCedronius: You might be right, but I don't want to hear the word "would". I want to hear "I tried it and it does (or doesn't)".

Comment: Maybe OP hasn't tried it, but I have. Lookup table is dead-slow compared with the `pshufb` trick. Using `popcnt` isn't much better than the `pshufb` trick.

Comment: @harold: Yeah that makes sense. Special hardware wins.

Comment: It's the memory accesses that kill your lookup table: The lookup table would fit into L1 cache on the OPs CPU (both are 64kiB), but the reading of the input data will evict at least half of that table from L1 cache. Consequently, you are doing L2 cache lookups most of the time, which makes it easy for a computation only approach to be faster.