# Optimizing Bitshift into Array

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-shift, uint8t, uint32

I have a piece of code that runs at ~1.2 million runs per second after performing some tasks, the bulkiest is setting a uint8_t array with bitshifted data from two uint32_t pieces of data. The excerpt code is as follows:

```
    static inline uint32_t RotateRight(uint32_t val, int n)
{
    return (val >> n) + (val << (32 - n));

}

static inline uint32_t CSUInt32BE(const uint8_t *b)
{
    return ((uint32_t)b[0] << 24) | ((uint32_t)b[1] << 16) | ((uint32_t)b[2] << 8) | (uint32_t)b[3];
}

static uint32_t ReverseBits(uint32_t val) // Usually just static, tried inline/static inline
{
    //  uint32_t res = 0;
    //  for (int i = 0; i<32; i++)
    //  {
    //      res <<= 1;
    //      res |= val & 1;
    //      val >>= 1;
    //  }
    // Original code above, benched ~220k l/s

    //val = ((val & 0x55555555) << 1) | ((val >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    //val = ((val & 0x33333333) << 2) | ((val >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    //val = ((val & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | ((val >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
    //val = ((val & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
    //val = (val << 16) | (val >> 16);
    // Option 0, benched ~770k on MBP

    uint32_t c = 0;
    c = (BitReverseTable256[val & 0xff] << 24) |
        (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) |
        (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) |
        (BitReverseTable256[val >> 24]); // was (val >> 24) & 0xff
                                         // Option 1, benched ~970k l/s on MBP, Current, minor tweak to 24

                                         //unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)&val;
                                         //unsigned char * q = (unsigned char *)&c;
                                         //q[3] = BitReverseTable256[p[0]];
                                         //q[2] = BitReverseTable256[p[1]];
                                         //q[1] = BitReverseTable256[p[2]];
                                         //q[0] = BitReverseTable256[p[3]];
                                         // Option 2 at ~970k l/s on MBP from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c


    return c; // Current
              //    return val; // option 0
              //    return res; // original


              //uint32_t m;
              //val = (val >> 16) | (val << 16);                            // swap halfwords
              //m = 0x00ff00ff; val = ((val >> 8) & m) | ((val << 8) & ~m); // swap bytes
              //m = m^(m << 4); val = ((val >> 4) & m) | ((val << 4) & ~m); // swap nibbles
              //m = m^(m << 2); val = ((val >> 2) & m) | ((val << 2) & ~m);
              //m = m^(m << 1); val = ((val >> 1) & m) | ((val << 1) & ~m);
              //return val;
              // Benches at 850k l/s on MBP

              //uint32_t t;
              //val = (val << 15) | (val >> 17);
              //t = (val ^ (val >> 10)) & 0x003f801f;
              //val = (t + (t << 10)) ^ val;
              //t = (val ^ (val >>  4)) & 0x0e038421;
              //val = (t + (t <<  4)) ^ val;
              //t = (val ^ (val >>  2)) & 0x22488842;
              //val = (t + (t <<  2)) ^ val;
              //return val;
              // Benches at 820k l/s on MBP
}
static void StuffItDESCrypt(uint8_t data[8], StuffItDESKeySchedule *ks, BOOL enc)
{
uint32_t left = ReverseBits(CSUInt32BE(&data[0]));
uint32_t right = ReverseBits(CSUInt32BE(&data[4]));

right = RotateRight(right, 29);
left = RotateRight(left, 29);

//Encryption function runs here

left = RotateRight(left, 3);
right = RotateRight(right, 3);

uint32_t left1 = ReverseBits(left);
uint32_t right1 = ReverseBits(right);

data[0] = right1 >> 24;
data[1] = (right1 >> 16) & 0xff;
data[2] = (right1 >> 8) & 0xff;
data[3] = right1 & 0xff;
data[4] = left1 >> 24;
data[5] = (left1 >> 16) & 0xff;
data[6] = (left1 >> 8) & 0xff;
data[7] = left1 & 0xff;
```

Is this the most optimal way to accomplish this? I have a uint64_t version as well:

```
uint64_t both = ((uint64_t)ReverseBits(left) << 32) | (uint64_t)ReverseBits(right);

data[0] = (both >> 24 & 0xff);
data[1] = (both >> 16) & 0xff;
data[2] = (both >> 8) & 0xff;
data[3] = both & 0xff; 
data[4] = (both >> 56);
data[5] = (both >> 48) & 0xff;
data[6] = (both >> 40) & 0xff;
data[7] = (both >> 32) & 0xff;
```

I tested what would happen if I completely skipped this assignment (the ReverseBits function is still done), and the code runs at ~6.5 million runs per second. In addition, this speed hit happens if I only do just one as well, leveling out at 1.2 million even without touching the other 7 assignments.

I'd hate to think that this operation takes a massive 80% speed hit due to this work and can't be made any faster.

This is on Windows Visual Studio 2015 (though I try to keep the source as portable to macOS and Linux as possible).

Edit: The full base code is at [Github](https://github.com/gregesposito/kasper4/blob/master/Kasper4/Kasper4.cpp). I am not the original author of the code, however I have forked it and maintain a password recovery solution using a modified for speed version. You can see my speed up successes in ReverseBits with various solutions and benched speeds.

These files are 20+ years old, and has successfully recovered files albeit at a low speed for years. See [blog post](http://www.kiwidget.com/kasper-stuffit-5-password-recovery/#comment-81250).

Comment: We cannot answer the question as posed.  "Most optimal" will depend at least to some extent on the context of the snippets you've presented and on the C implementation you use.  If you present a [mcve], however, then we may at least be able to suggest some things to try.

Comment: Post all your definitions. What is left? What ReverseBits is doing? Etc.

Comment: what data type is `data[]`? is it byte or unsigned char?

Comment: he said uint8_t

Comment: I am attempting to optimize the function StuffitDESCrypt [here](https://github.com/gregesposito/kasper4/blob/master/Kasper4/Kasper4.cpp). Most specifically, by trying to replace CSSetUInt32BE(&data[0], ReverseBits(right)); and CSSetUInt32BE(&data[4], ReverseBits(left));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're certainly doing more work than you need to do.  Note how function `ReverseBits()` goes to some effort to put the bytes of the reversed word in the correct order, and how the next thing that happens -- the part to which you are attributing the slowdown -- is to reorder those same bytes.

You could write and use a modified version of `ReverseBits()` that puts the bytes of the reversed representation directly into the correct places in the array, instead of packing them into integers just to unpack them again.  That ought to be at least a bit faster, as you would be strictly removing operations.

Comment: I made a modified ReverseBits as such 

`static inline void     ReverseBits_direct(uint8_t *b, uint64_t val)
{
 b[0] = (BitReverseTable256[val & 0xff]);
 b[1] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 8 & 0xff)]);
 b[2] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 16 & 0xff)]);
 b[3] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 24 & 0xff)]);
 b[4] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 32 & 0xff)]);
 b[5] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 40 & 0xff)]);
 b[6] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 48 & 0xff)]);
 b[7] = (BitReverseTable256[(val >> 56)]);
}` 

and i'd say the speed has increased to 1.3Mil (and the code is certainly cleaner)

Comment: @GregEsposito, I can't say I'm surprised that the enhancement is comparatively small.  To be honest, I find your relative performance measurements suspicious; if recording the updated data in the array is truly as costly as you (think you've) measured then there is likely to be a more subtle effect in play, such as effectiveness of cache usage.  It's possible, in fact, that the speedup you observed arises largely from just not having to write modified data back to main memory, so that the perceived opportunity for improvement is illusory.

Comment: Yeah, by commenting out the entire function, it's 6 million per, but with just a single setting its 1.2-1.3 Million (measured by a lines/second count at 1m, 10m, 100m, 1 billion tries). I can absolutely believe that the hit comes from just touching the data vs no-op'ing it. My goal now will be to move the data types to uint64 and approach other ways to optimize the codebase. Considering I'm on dual Xeon X5365 processors there's some tech I'm unable to take advantage of but lots of cores to throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought was to "view" the `int32_t` as if they were an array of `int8_t` like

```
uint8_t data2[8];
*((uint32_t*)&data2[0]) = right1;
*((uint32_t*)&data2[4]) = left1;
```

However, you store the most significant bits of `right1` in `data[0]`, whereas this approach lets the least significant bits go to `data[0]`. Anyway, as I do not know what `ReverseBits` does and whether you could also adapt your code according to a different order, maybe it helps...

Comment: If that produced the right result then it would be worth a shot.  Unfortunately, it won't do so on a little-endian platform, such as all those that MSVC runs on, because the bytes are being recorded in `data` in big-endian order.