# Decimal to binary in C language

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I wrote simple code in C language (without libraries), but the result is good only when you read it from right to left, how to reverse it? I want the most simplified code as it is possible. My code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;

    printf("Changes from decimal to binary\n");
    printf("Enter the number: ");

    scanf("%d",&number);

    do{
        if(number % 2 == 1){
            printf("1");
        }else{
            printf("0");
        }
        number = number / 2;
    }
     while(number>0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Allocate a character array for the output; replace your "printf"s with code that places each character into that array, back to front; print the array at the end.

Comment: If you want to reuse the code you've already written you can just reverse the bits in the integer before printing it out using your function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/most-efficient-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c. Btw, your code uses the variable 'liczba' which is not defined anywhere, I think you meant to use 'number'. Also, there is a bug for negative numbers. Any negative number modulo 2 will give either 0 or -1, rather than 1.

Comment: the posted code is starting from the least significant digit of the value.  Start from the most significant digit  -or- write a small function to reverse a string 'inplace' (about 5 lines of code).   Use google to search for a function that performs the desired reverse of a string

Answer (score 0):

You could store the binary number in an array and then print it backwards. So you would have for example `int binaryDigits[1024];` and then instead of printing you will store the number in the array with a counter. Before the loop: `int i = 0;` and after that instead of `printf("1");` and `printf("0");`, `binaryDigits[i++] = 1` and `binaryDigits[i++] = 0` respectively. Finally you could print the number in order with a for loop:

```
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%d", binaryDigits[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion and print the digits as you fall off the stack.  I changed `number` from `int` to `unsigned int`.

```
void print_dec_to_bin_hlp(unsigned int number)
{
    if(number > 0)
    {
        print_dec_to_bin_hlp(number/2);
        printf("%d", (number%2));
    }
}

void print_dec_to_bin(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number == 0) printf("%d", number);
    else print_dec_to_bin_hlp(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution using bitwise operations, for unsigned integers:

```
void print_binary(unsigned int num) {
    if(num >> 1) print_binary(num >> 1);
    putchar(num & 1 ? '1' : '0');
}
```

The bitwise operators `>>`, `&`, etc. access the bits in the value. The bits form a binary representation of the number. `>>` shifts the bits to the right, where the bits are ordered from MSB (most significant bit) to LSB, like the normal way numbers are written.

`num & 1` returns non-zero only if the LSB (rightmost) bit is set. (AND mask with ..0001). So `(num >> 1) & 1` does the same on the second-rightmost bit. So this recursive function prints the bits in MSB to LSB order.

The `if(num >> 1)` check makes sure prefix zeroes are not printed: If after the rightshift, `num` is all-zeroes, it is not printed any further. The check is made outside the function call, so that `print_binary(0)` (initial call) will still always print a single `0`.

For signed integers:

```
void print_signed_binary(int num) {
    if(num < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        print_binary(-num);
    } else {
        print_binary(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in your first solution do you shift the number rather than the mask? And the recursive one will fail if the type is signed and you feed it a negative number, otherwise it's a very elegant solution.