# Understanding the given snippet on bit reversal

Tags: c++

I found this snippet on 'codefights' submitted by a programmer. My solution to the problem was 30 lines, whereas this is just a beauty.
But I am not able to understand the logic.
Can anyone explain this.

```
int mirrorBits(int a) {
 int r = 0;

 for (; a; a >>= 1) 
    r = r << 1 | a & 1;  
 return r;
}
```

input a = 8; output : 1

Comment: As long as `a != 0`, you left shift `r` by `1` and add the least significant bit of `a`.  Then you right shift `a` by `1` to deal with the next bit, if any.

Comment: This is a wrong code, it does not do what it names. The mirror of 8 is not 1.

Comment: @S.M.: Doesn’t it? Take a binary representation with no leading zeros and reverse it.

Comment: @S.M.What should it return, then ?

Comment: @Ry why you want to remove leading zeroes? Mirroring of mirror should give in result an initial value. 8 -> 1 -> 1 is not correct.

Comment: @S.M. It goes like this: 8 in binary is 1000, mirror it, it will become 0001, which is anyways 1 only.

Comment: @SidS Thanks...it does explain...so simple it is.

Comment: @S.M.: Because that’s the task, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is a very good StackOverflow answer here:
[Most Efficient Algorithm for Bit Reversal ( from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/most-efficient-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c)

The algorithm makes use of

```
>> ... binary shift right (100b >> 1 == 10b)
<< ... binary shift left (100b << 1 == 1000b
| .... binary or (100b | 10b == 110b)
& .... binary and (111b & 100b == 100b)
```

The for loop shifts a to the right until all bits have fallen out of a.

Imagine you start with a = 101101 then a >>= 1 does the following:

```
At the end of loop 1:  a == 10110
At the end of loop 2:  a == 01011
At the end of loop 3:  a == 00101
At the end of loop 4:  a == 00010
At the end of loop 5:  a == 00001
At the end of loop 6:  a == 00000 (condition fails -> loop ends)
```

The body of the loop shifts b one bit right, uses & to mask the last bit of a and adds it as last digit to b. The or can be used to add the last digit because << inserts 0 for all "new" bits.

Imagine you start with a = 101101

- loop 1: a = 10110**1**, r = 0 => 0**1**
- loop 2: a = 01011**0**, r = 01 => 01**0**
- loop 3: a = 00101**1**, r = 010 => 010**1**
- loop 4: a = 00010**1**, r = 0101 => 0101**1**
- loop 5: a = 00001**0**, r = 01011 => 01011**0**
- loop 6: a = 00000**1**, r = 010110 => 010110**1**

In detail the inner loop #3 does the following:
(a is 001011 and r is 010)

r << 1 changes r from 010 to 0100. The last digit is the inserted 0.
a & 1 masks the current last bit from a (the 1 in 00101**1**)
now we have (0100 | 1) which has the result 0101.

**Warning**: This algorithm is not really mirroring the bits, because you do not get the original value if you apply the algorithm to the result.

If you need a mirrored 32-bit unsigned integer you have to loop 32 times independently of the value of a:

```
unsigned int r = 0;
unsigned int a = 12345;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
   r = (r << 1) | (a & 1);
   a >>= 1;
}
```

If you apply this algorithm twice, you should get the original value.