# Most efficent way to calculate CRC64 with reflected input

Tags: c, performance, crc, crc32, crc64

I need to calculate a CRC-64 using [this setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdj7Z.png) into this wonderful website: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

As you can see I require "input reflected" and that means that I need to reverse the bit order of any byte (a bit annoying).
For the moment, I implemented this with a lookup table (for example 0x55 -> 0xAA), but I was wondering if there is any property of CRC which can be used to be more efficient.

This is my code (in C):

```
static const unsigned long long CRC64_TABLE[256] = {
    0x0000000000000000, 0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693, 0x85E1C3D753D46D26, 0xC711223CFA3E5BB5, 0x493366450E42ECDF, 0x0BC387AEA7A8DA4C, 0xCCD2A5925D9681F9, 0x8E224479F47CB76A,
    0x9266CC8A1C85D9BE, 0xD0962D61B56FEF2D, 0x17870F5D4F51B498, 0x5577EEB6E6BB820B, 0xDB55AACF12C73561, 0x99A54B24BB2D03F2, 0x5EB4691841135847, 0x1C4488F3E8F96ED4,
    0x663D78FF90E185EF, 0x24CD9914390BB37C, 0xE3DCBB28C335E8C9, 0xA12C5AC36ADFDE5A, 0x2F0E1EBA9EA36930, 0x6DFEFF5137495FA3, 0xAAEFDD6DCD770416, 0xE81F3C86649D3285,
    0xF45BB4758C645C51, 0xB6AB559E258E6AC2, 0x71BA77A2DFB03177, 0x334A9649765A07E4, 0xBD68D2308226B08E, 0xFF9833DB2BCC861D, 0x388911E7D1F2DDA8, 0x7A79F00C7818EB3B,
    0xCC7AF1FF21C30BDE, 0x8E8A101488293D4D, 0x499B3228721766F8, 0x0B6BD3C3DBFD506B, 0x854997BA2F81E701, 0xC7B97651866BD192, 0x00A8546D7C558A27, 0x4258B586D5BFBCB4,
    0x5E1C3D753D46D260, 0x1CECDC9E94ACE4F3, 0xDBFDFEA26E92BF46, 0x990D1F49C77889D5, 0x172F5B3033043EBF, 0x55DFBADB9AEE082C, 0x92CE98E760D05399, 0xD03E790CC93A650A,
    0xAA478900B1228E31, 0xE8B768EB18C8B8A2, 0x2FA64AD7E2F6E317, 0x6D56AB3C4B1CD584, 0xE374EF45BF6062EE, 0xA1840EAE168A547D, 0x66952C92ECB40FC8, 0x2465CD79455E395B,
    0x3821458AADA7578F, 0x7AD1A461044D611C, 0xBDC0865DFE733AA9, 0xFF3067B657990C3A, 0x711223CFA3E5BB50, 0x33E2C2240A0F8DC3, 0xF4F3E018F031D676, 0xB60301F359DBE0E5,
    0xDA050215EA6C212F, 0x98F5E3FE438617BC, 0x5FE4C1C2B9B84C09, 0x1D14202910527A9A, 0x93366450E42ECDF0, 0xD1C685BB4DC4FB63, 0x16D7A787B7FAA0D6, 0x5427466C1E109645,
    0x4863CE9FF6E9F891, 0x0A932F745F03CE02, 0xCD820D48A53D95B7, 0x8F72ECA30CD7A324, 0x0150A8DAF8AB144E, 0x43A04931514122DD, 0x84B16B0DAB7F7968, 0xC6418AE602954FFB,
    0xBC387AEA7A8DA4C0, 0xFEC89B01D3679253, 0x39D9B93D2959C9E6, 0x7B2958D680B3FF75, 0xF50B1CAF74CF481F, 0xB7FBFD44DD257E8C, 0x70EADF78271B2539, 0x321A3E938EF113AA,
    0x2E5EB66066087D7E, 0x6CAE578BCFE24BED, 0xABBF75B735DC1058, 0xE94F945C9C3626CB, 0x676DD025684A91A1, 0x259D31CEC1A0A732, 0xE28C13F23B9EFC87, 0xA07CF2199274CA14,
    0x167FF3EACBAF2AF1, 0x548F120162451C62, 0x939E303D987B47D7, 0xD16ED1D631917144, 0x5F4C95AFC5EDC62E, 0x1DBC74446C07F0BD, 0xDAAD56789639AB08, 0x985DB7933FD39D9B,
    0x84193F60D72AF34F, 0xC6E9DE8B7EC0C5DC, 0x01F8FCB784FE9E69, 0x43081D5C2D14A8FA, 0xCD2A5925D9681F90, 0x8FDAB8CE70822903, 0x48CB9AF28ABC72B6, 0x0A3B7B1923564425,
    0x70428B155B4EAF1E, 0x32B26AFEF2A4998D, 0xF5A348C2089AC238, 0xB753A929A170F4AB, 0x3971ED50550C43C1, 0x7B810CBBFCE67552, 0xBC902E8706D82EE7, 0xFE60CF6CAF321874,
    0xE224479F47CB76A0, 0xA0D4A674EE214033, 0x67C58448141F1B86, 0x253565A3BDF52D15, 0xAB1721DA49899A7F, 0xE9E7C031E063ACEC, 0x2EF6E20D1A5DF759, 0x6C0603E6B3B7C1CA,
    0xF6FAE5C07D3274CD, 0xB40A042BD4D8425E, 0x731B26172EE619EB, 0x31EBC7FC870C2F78, 0xBFC9838573709812, 0xFD39626EDA9AAE81, 0x3A28405220A4F534, 0x78D8A1B9894EC3A7,
    0x649C294A61B7AD73, 0x266CC8A1C85D9BE0, 0xE17DEA9D3263C055, 0xA38D0B769B89F6C6, 0x2DAF4F0F6FF541AC, 0x6F5FAEE4C61F773F, 0xA84E8CD83C212C8A, 0xEABE6D3395CB1A19,
    0x90C79D3FEDD3F122, 0xD2377CD44439C7B1, 0x15265EE8BE079C04, 0x57D6BF0317EDAA97, 0xD9F4FB7AE3911DFD, 0x9B041A914A7B2B6E, 0x5C1538ADB04570DB, 0x1EE5D94619AF4648,
    0x02A151B5F156289C, 0x4051B05E58BC1E0F, 0x87409262A28245BA, 0xC5B073890B687329, 0x4B9237F0FF14C443, 0x0962D61B56FEF2D0, 0xCE73F427ACC0A965, 0x8C8315CC052A9FF6,
    0x3A80143F5CF17F13, 0x7870F5D4F51B4980, 0xBF61D7E80F251235, 0xFD913603A6CF24A6, 0x73B3727A52B393CC, 0x31439391FB59A55F, 0xF652B1AD0167FEEA, 0xB4A25046A88DC879,
    0xA8E6D8B54074A6AD, 0xEA16395EE99E903E, 0x2D071B6213A0CB8B, 0x6FF7FA89BA4AFD18, 0xE1D5BEF04E364A72, 0xA3255F1BE7DC7CE1, 0x64347D271DE22754, 0x26C49CCCB40811C7,
    0x5CBD6CC0CC10FAFC, 0x1E4D8D2B65FACC6F, 0xD95CAF179FC497DA, 0x9BAC4EFC362EA149, 0x158E0A85C2521623, 0x577EEB6E6BB820B0, 0x906FC95291867B05, 0xD29F28B9386C4D96,
    0xCEDBA04AD0952342, 0x8C2B41A1797F15D1, 0x4B3A639D83414E64, 0x09CA82762AAB78F7, 0x87E8C60FDED7CF9D, 0xC51827E4773DF90E, 0x020905D88D03A2BB, 0x40F9E43324E99428,
    0x2CFFE7D5975E55E2, 0x6E0F063E3EB46371, 0xA91E2402C48A38C4, 0xEBEEC5E96D600E57, 0x65CC8190991CB93D, 0x273C607B30F68FAE, 0xE02D4247CAC8D41B, 0xA2DDA3AC6322E288,
    0xBE992B5F8BDB8C5C, 0xFC69CAB42231BACF, 0x3B78E888D80FE17A, 0x7988096371E5D7E9, 0xF7AA4D1A85996083, 0xB55AACF12C735610, 0x724B8ECDD64D0DA5, 0x30BB6F267FA73B36,
    0x4AC29F2A07BFD00D, 0x08327EC1AE55E69E, 0xCF235CFD546BBD2B, 0x8DD3BD16FD818BB8, 0x03F1F96F09FD3CD2, 0x41011884A0170A41, 0x86103AB85A2951F4, 0xC4E0DB53F3C36767,
    0xD8A453A01B3A09B3, 0x9A54B24BB2D03F20, 0x5D45907748EE6495, 0x1FB5719CE1045206, 0x919735E51578E56C, 0xD367D40EBC92D3FF, 0x1476F63246AC884A, 0x568617D9EF46BED9,
    0xE085162AB69D5E3C, 0xA275F7C11F7768AF, 0x6564D5FDE549331A, 0x279434164CA30589, 0xA9B6706FB8DFB2E3, 0xEB46918411358470, 0x2C57B3B8EB0BDFC5, 0x6EA7525342E1E956,
    0x72E3DAA0AA188782, 0x30133B4B03F2B111, 0xF7021977F9CCEAA4, 0xB5F2F89C5026DC37, 0x3BD0BCE5A45A6B5D, 0x79205D0E0DB05DCE, 0xBE317F32F78E067B, 0xFCC19ED95E6430E8,
    0x86B86ED5267CDBD3, 0xC4488F3E8F96ED40, 0x0359AD0275A8B6F5, 0x41A94CE9DC428066, 0xCF8B0890283E370C, 0x8D7BE97B81D4019F, 0x4A6ACB477BEA5A2A, 0x089A2AACD2006CB9,
    0x14DEA25F3AF9026D, 0x562E43B4931334FE, 0x913F6188692D6F4B, 0xD3CF8063C0C759D8, 0x5DEDC41A34BBEEB2, 0x1F1D25F19D51D821, 0xD80C07CD676F8394, 0x9AFCE626CE85B507
};

static const unsigned char REVERSE_BITS_TABLE[256] = {
    // 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     A     B     C     D     E     F
    0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xC0, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x60, 0xE0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xD0, 0x30, 0xB0, 0x70, 0xF0,
    0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xC8, 0x28, 0xA8, 0x68, 0xE8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xD8, 0x38, 0xB8, 0x78, 0xF8,
    0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x24, 0xA4, 0x64, 0xE4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xD4, 0x34, 0xB4, 0x74, 0xF4,
    0x0C, 0x8C, 0x4C, 0xCC, 0x2C, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x9C, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xFC,
    0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xC2, 0x22, 0xA2, 0x62, 0xE2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xD2, 0x32, 0xB2, 0x72, 0xF2,
    0x0A, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0xCA, 0x2A, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0x1A, 0x9A, 0x5A, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0xBA, 0x7A, 0xFA,
    0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xC6, 0x26, 0xA6, 0x66, 0xE6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xD6, 0x36, 0xB6, 0x76, 0xF6,
    0x0E, 0x8E, 0x4E, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0xAE, 0x6E, 0xEE, 0x1E, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0xDE, 0x3E, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0xFE,
    0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xC1, 0x21, 0xA1, 0x61, 0xE1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xD1, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x71, 0xF1,
    0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xC9, 0x29, 0xA9, 0x69, 0xE9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xD9, 0x39, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xF9,
    0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xC5, 0x25, 0xA5, 0x65, 0xE5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xD5, 0x35, 0xB5, 0x75, 0xF5,
    0x0D, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0xCD, 0x2D, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xED, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x5D, 0xDD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0x7D, 0xFD,
    0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xC3, 0x23, 0xA3, 0x63, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xD3, 0x33, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xF3,
    0x0B, 0x8B, 0x4B, 0xCB, 0x2B, 0xAB, 0x6B, 0xEB, 0x1B, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0xDB, 0x3B, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0xFB,
    0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xC7, 0x27, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xD7, 0x37, 0xB7, 0x77, 0xF7,
    0x0F, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0xCF, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x1F, 0x9F, 0x5F, 0xDF, 0x3F, 0xBF, 0x7F, 0xFF
};

unsigned long long calculateCRC64(unsigned char* data, unsigned long size)
{
    unsigned long long myCRC64 = 0;

    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
        myCRC64 = CRC64_TABLE[((myCRC64 >> 56) ^ REVERSE_BITS_TABLE[data[i]]) & 0xFF] ^ (myCRC64 << 8);

    return myCRC64;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Update: actually I'm wondering if some properties of CRC allow me to get the same result using reflected table, opposite shifting, reciprocal / reverse polynomial... etc. That would let skip the step of reversing bits.

**Solution**: using reflected table, changing shift direction and reversing bits just of the very last result:

```
static const unsigned long long CRC64_TABLE_REF[256] = {
    0x0000000000000000, 0xB32E4CBE03A75F6F, 0xF4843657A840A05B, 0x47AA7AE9ABE7FF34, 0x7BD0C384FF8F5E33, 0xC8FE8F3AFC28015C, 0x8F54F5D357CFFE68, 0x3C7AB96D5468A107,
    0xF7A18709FF1EBC66, 0x448FCBB7FCB9E309, 0x0325B15E575E1C3D, 0xB00BFDE054F94352, 0x8C71448D0091E255, 0x3F5F08330336BD3A, 0x78F572DAA8D1420E, 0xCBDB3E64AB761D61,
    0x7D9BA13851336649, 0xCEB5ED8652943926, 0x891F976FF973C612, 0x3A31DBD1FAD4997D, 0x064B62BCAEBC387A, 0xB5652E02AD1B6715, 0xF2CF54EB06FC9821, 0x41E11855055BC74E,
    0x8A3A2631AE2DDA2F, 0x39146A8FAD8A8540, 0x7EBE1066066D7A74, 0xCD905CD805CA251B, 0xF1EAE5B551A2841C, 0x42C4A90B5205DB73, 0x056ED3E2F9E22447, 0xB6409F5CFA457B28,
    0xFB374270A266CC92, 0x48190ECEA1C193FD, 0x0FB374270A266CC9, 0xBC9D3899098133A6, 0x80E781F45DE992A1, 0x33C9CD4A5E4ECDCE, 0x7463B7A3F5A932FA, 0xC74DFB1DF60E6D95,
    0x0C96C5795D7870F4, 0xBFB889C75EDF2F9B, 0xF812F32EF538D0AF, 0x4B3CBF90F69F8FC0, 0x774606FDA2F72EC7, 0xC4684A43A15071A8, 0x83C230AA0AB78E9C, 0x30EC7C140910D1F3,
    0x86ACE348F355AADB, 0x3582AFF6F0F2F5B4, 0x7228D51F5B150A80, 0xC10699A158B255EF, 0xFD7C20CC0CDAF4E8, 0x4E526C720F7DAB87, 0x09F8169BA49A54B3, 0xBAD65A25A73D0BDC,
    0x710D64410C4B16BD, 0xC22328FF0FEC49D2, 0x85895216A40BB6E6, 0x36A71EA8A7ACE989, 0x0ADDA7C5F3C4488E, 0xB9F3EB7BF06317E1, 0xFE5991925B84E8D5, 0x4D77DD2C5823B7BA,
    0x64B62BCAEBC387A1, 0xD7986774E864D8CE, 0x90321D9D438327FA, 0x231C512340247895, 0x1F66E84E144CD992, 0xAC48A4F017EB86FD, 0xEBE2DE19BC0C79C9, 0x58CC92A7BFAB26A6,
    0x9317ACC314DD3BC7, 0x2039E07D177A64A8, 0x67939A94BC9D9B9C, 0xD4BDD62ABF3AC4F3, 0xE8C76F47EB5265F4, 0x5BE923F9E8F53A9B, 0x1C4359104312C5AF, 0xAF6D15AE40B59AC0,
    0x192D8AF2BAF0E1E8, 0xAA03C64CB957BE87, 0xEDA9BCA512B041B3, 0x5E87F01B11171EDC, 0x62FD4976457FBFDB, 0xD1D305C846D8E0B4, 0x96797F21ED3F1F80, 0x2557339FEE9840EF,
    0xEE8C0DFB45EE5D8E, 0x5DA24145464902E1, 0x1A083BACEDAEFDD5, 0xA9267712EE09A2BA, 0x955CCE7FBA6103BD, 0x267282C1B9C65CD2, 0x61D8F8281221A3E6, 0xD2F6B4961186FC89,
    0x9F8169BA49A54B33, 0x2CAF25044A02145C, 0x6B055FEDE1E5EB68, 0xD82B1353E242B407, 0xE451AA3EB62A1500, 0x577FE680B58D4A6F, 0x10D59C691E6AB55B, 0xA3FBD0D71DCDEA34,
    0x6820EEB3B6BBF755, 0xDB0EA20DB51CA83A, 0x9CA4D8E41EFB570E, 0x2F8A945A1D5C0861, 0x13F02D374934A966, 0xA0DE61894A93F609, 0xE7741B60E174093D, 0x545A57DEE2D35652,
    0xE21AC88218962D7A, 0x5134843C1B317215, 0x169EFED5B0D68D21, 0xA5B0B26BB371D24E, 0x99CA0B06E7197349, 0x2AE447B8E4BE2C26, 0x6D4E3D514F59D312, 0xDE6071EF4CFE8C7D,
    0x15BB4F8BE788911C, 0xA6950335E42FCE73, 0xE13F79DC4FC83147, 0x521135624C6F6E28, 0x6E6B8C0F1807CF2F, 0xDD45C0B11BA09040, 0x9AEFBA58B0476F74, 0x29C1F6E6B3E0301B,
    0xC96C5795D7870F42, 0x7A421B2BD420502D, 0x3DE861C27FC7AF19, 0x8EC62D7C7C60F076, 0xB2BC941128085171, 0x0192D8AF2BAF0E1E, 0x4638A2468048F12A, 0xF516EEF883EFAE45,
    0x3ECDD09C2899B324, 0x8DE39C222B3EEC4B, 0xCA49E6CB80D9137F, 0x7967AA75837E4C10, 0x451D1318D716ED17, 0xF6335FA6D4B1B278, 0xB199254F7F564D4C, 0x02B769F17CF11223,
    0xB4F7F6AD86B4690B, 0x07D9BA1385133664, 0x4073C0FA2EF4C950, 0xF35D8C442D53963F, 0xCF273529793B3738, 0x7C0979977A9C6857, 0x3BA3037ED17B9763, 0x888D4FC0D2DCC80C,
    0x435671A479AAD56D, 0xF0783D1A7A0D8A02, 0xB7D247F3D1EA7536, 0x04FC0B4DD24D2A59, 0x3886B22086258B5E, 0x8BA8FE9E8582D431, 0xCC0284772E652B05, 0x7F2CC8C92DC2746A,
    0x325B15E575E1C3D0, 0x8175595B76469CBF, 0xC6DF23B2DDA1638B, 0x75F16F0CDE063CE4, 0x498BD6618A6E9DE3, 0xFAA59ADF89C9C28C, 0xBD0FE036222E3DB8, 0x0E21AC88218962D7,
    0xC5FA92EC8AFF7FB6, 0x76D4DE52895820D9, 0x317EA4BB22BFDFED, 0x8250E80521188082, 0xBE2A516875702185, 0x0D041DD676D77EEA, 0x4AAE673FDD3081DE, 0xF9802B81DE97DEB1,
    0x4FC0B4DD24D2A599, 0xFCEEF8632775FAF6, 0xBB44828A8C9205C2, 0x086ACE348F355AAD, 0x34107759DB5DFBAA, 0x873E3BE7D8FAA4C5, 0xC094410E731D5BF1, 0x73BA0DB070BA049E,
    0xB86133D4DBCC19FF, 0x0B4F7F6AD86B4690, 0x4CE50583738CB9A4, 0xFFCB493D702BE6CB, 0xC3B1F050244347CC, 0x709FBCEE27E418A3, 0x3735C6078C03E797, 0x841B8AB98FA4B8F8,
    0xADDA7C5F3C4488E3, 0x1EF430E13FE3D78C, 0x595E4A08940428B8, 0xEA7006B697A377D7, 0xD60ABFDBC3CBD6D0, 0x6524F365C06C89BF, 0x228E898C6B8B768B, 0x91A0C532682C29E4,
    0x5A7BFB56C35A3485, 0xE955B7E8C0FD6BEA, 0xAEFFCD016B1A94DE, 0x1DD181BF68BDCBB1, 0x21AB38D23CD56AB6, 0x9285746C3F7235D9, 0xD52F0E859495CAED, 0x6601423B97329582,
    0xD041DD676D77EEAA, 0x636F91D96ED0B1C5, 0x24C5EB30C5374EF1, 0x97EBA78EC690119E, 0xAB911EE392F8B099, 0x18BF525D915FEFF6, 0x5F1528B43AB810C2, 0xEC3B640A391F4FAD,
    0x27E05A6E926952CC, 0x94CE16D091CE0DA3, 0xD3646C393A29F297, 0x604A2087398EADF8, 0x5C3099EA6DE60CFF, 0xEF1ED5546E415390, 0xA8B4AFBDC5A6ACA4, 0x1B9AE303C601F3CB,
    0x56ED3E2F9E224471, 0xE5C372919D851B1E, 0xA26908783662E42A, 0x114744C635C5BB45, 0x2D3DFDAB61AD1A42, 0x9E13B115620A452D, 0xD9B9CBFCC9EDBA19, 0x6A978742CA4AE576,
    0xA14CB926613CF817, 0x1262F598629BA778, 0x55C88F71C97C584C, 0xE6E6C3CFCADB0723, 0xDA9C7AA29EB3A624, 0x69B2361C9D14F94B, 0x2E184CF536F3067F, 0x9D36004B35545910,
    0x2B769F17CF112238, 0x9858D3A9CCB67D57, 0xDFF2A94067518263, 0x6CDCE5FE64F6DD0C, 0x50A65C93309E7C0B, 0xE388102D33392364, 0xA4226AC498DEDC50, 0x170C267A9B79833F,
    0xDCD7181E300F9E5E, 0x6FF954A033A8C131, 0x28532E49984F3E05, 0x9B7D62F79BE8616A, 0xA707DB9ACF80C06D, 0x14299724CC279F02, 0x5383EDCD67C06036, 0xE0ADA17364673F59
};

unsigned long long calculateCRC64(unsigned char* data, unsigned long size)
{
    unsigned long long myCRC64 = 0;

    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
        myCRC64 = CRC64_TABLE_REF[(myCRC64 ^ data[i]) & 0xFF] ^ (myCRC64 >> 8);

    unsigned long long tmp = myCRC64;
    myCRC64 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        myCRC64 = (myCRC64 << 1) | (tmp & 1);
        tmp >>= 1;
    }

    return myCRC64;
}
```

Thanks to everybody for the help!

Comment: ARM, for example, has a assembly command that reverses bits: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihjgdid.htm

Comment: Thanks! That could be interesting, I will try it!

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/efficient-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> actually I'm wondering if some properties of CRC allow me to get the same result using reflected table, opposite shifting, reciprocal / reverse polynomial... etc. That would let skip the step of reversing bits.

There is such a property, and you only need *one* reverse, in the end. The whole logic of the CRC can be bit-reversed*, so that the bits stream the opposite way and don't need to be reversed during the calculation itself:

```
unsigned long long CRC64(unsigned char* data, unsigned long size)
{
    unsigned long long crc = 0;

    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
        crc = CRC64_TABLE_R[(crc & 0xff) ^ data[i]] ^ (crc >> 8);

    return rbit(crc);
}
```

`CRC64_TABLE_R` is like `CRC64_TABLE`, but with the entries *and indexes* both bit-reversed. So they relate to each other like this: (naturally you would hard-code this table)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    CRC64_TABLE_R[REVERSE_BITS_TABLE[i]] = rbit(CRC64_TABLE[i]);
}
```

`rbit` is just some function that reverses bits, I used this really dumb one, use a better one if you want but it's only used once:

```
unsigned long long rbit(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        x = (x << 1) | (n & 1);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

*: really what this means is that the integer holding the bits during the calculation is viewed in reverse, with what would normally be its least significant bit instead held in its most significant bit etc. So depending on how you look at it, the calculation is not even different. The same bits are created, but we hold them in a variable differently.

Answer (score 3):

The code just needs to switch from a left shifting CRC to a right shifting CRC, with the polynomial bits reversed. The "#if 0" is used to select between two common polynomials, in this case, "#if 0" will use CRC64 ecma, which is what is shown in the question's CRC table. (0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693 bit reversed == 0xC96C5795D7870F42).

```
uint64_t crctbl[256];

void gentbl(void)
{
uint64_t crc;
uint64_t b;
uint64_t c;
uint64_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b = crc&1;
            crc >>= 1;
#if 0
            crc ^= (0 - b) & 0xd800000000000000ull; // crc64 iso
#else
            crc ^= (0 - b) & 0xc96c5795d7870f42ull; // crc64 ecma
#endif
        }
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

uint64_t crc64c(uint64_t crc64, uint8_t * bfr, size_t size)
{
uint64_t crc = crc64;
    while(size--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctbl[(crc & 0xff)^*bfr++];
    return(crc);
}
```

---

"Most efficient way" - if running on X86 X64 with carryless multiply, a really fast CRC, over 20 times as fast as the table method shown above (For a CRC of 256 MB of data, Intel Core i7-10510U .475 seconds table, .015 seconds pclmulqdq, 31.5 times as fast) , can be performed using pclmulqdq instruction and xmm registers. Link to a zip of a 520+ line assembly file, for Visual Studio's MASM (ML64.EXE), for 64 bit reflected CRC, with the same "if 0" as the gentbl() function above to choose between the two CRC polynomials.

http://rcgldr.net/misc/crc64ra.zip

Intel document explaining the algorithm for a 32 bit CRC:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf

A carryless multiply of two 64 bit non-reflected operands produces a 127 bit product in bits 126 (msb) to bit 0 (lsb). For reflected operands, a carryless multiply effectively multiplies the product by 2, which is taken into account with the constants. For 64 bit CRC, the poly is 65 bits, so some adjustments are also needed to handle that.