# Bit reversal and bitwise operators in the FFT

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, fft

I'm studying the fast Fourier transform algorithm (FFT) and I noted that every algorithm uses a "direct" bit reversal operation, in the sense that it gives the bit reversed of the initial vector components using bitwise operators. By the way I think there exist "indirect" methods which do not use these operators. So I'm asking what are the prons and cons of the two approaches? Are, in general, statements with bitwise operators faster than other statements performing the same task without bitwise operators?

I already read this post: [Efficient Algorithm for Bit Reversal (from MSB->LSB to LSB->MSB) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/efficient-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c).
However it seems they suppose one MUST use bitwise operators to do bit reversing. So I would like to know why an FFT algorithm not using bitwise operators (e.g. the following) should not be fine:

```
void bitrev(int* a, int n)
{
    int i, k, s, p;
    int l = log2(n);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        s = 0;
        p = 1;
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            s += ((i / p) % 2) * n / (2 * p);
            p = p * 2;
        }
        if (s < i) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[s]);
        }
    }
}
```

Put in another way, the underlying question is: what are the differences (in terms of time) between FFT algorithms involving bitwise operators and not? Is it always preferable to act directly on the bits?

Comment: Can you explain these indirect methods?

Comment: I mean swapping vector components according to a pattern depending on the number of components (powers of 2)

Comment: How about an example of both since you are asking for a comparison?

Comment: Well, I can't find an example of an algorithm without bitwise operators. But I'm writing one as an excercise

Comment: The only way to know if one implementation is faster than another is to run them both and time them. Some version will be fastest on your machine, but might be the slower one on a different machine.

Comment: reversing bits is obviously a bitwise operation because it operates on bits individually. Any other methods like numerical, if any, will be far slower. For example `int l = log2(n);` in your example is a floating-point logarithm and will take hundreds or thousands of cycles just for the log. In C++ there are `std::bit_floor` and `std::bit_ceil` which are far faster but they're still bitwise methods and compiled to bitwise instructions

Comment: @phuclv The alternative in this case is swapping elements around in the array. This question is very specific, it is not a generic question about bit operations.

Comment: Here's a paper comparing several methods, including some bitwise and some not (ie without explicitly reversing any bits, which is not required to perform the permutation): https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.01873

Comment: Thank you to all for the reply. So, if I understood correctly, in this specific case (bit reversal) it is faster to operate on the bits themeselves, but this is not a general rule. Thank you for the paper, I'll read it.